# Qual é a diferença entre UNION e UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, union, union-all

Qual é a diferença entre `UNION` e `UNION ALL`? Se possível, incluir exemplos de uso.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basicamente tem a ver com linhas **duplicadas**. `UNION` combinará linhas das demais tabelas combinadas que já existam no resultado das consultas aplicadas nas tabelas anteriores. `UNION ALL` não se importará com isso.

Para quem não sabe, `UNION` combina dados de uma tabela com outra linearmente. Não é como um `JOIN` que se faz por relacionamento, ele faz uma "soma" simples da linhas de uma tabela com outra(s). As colunas das tabelas envolvidas precisam ser as mesmas (quantidade e tipos nas devidas posições). É como colocar uma embaixo da outra.

Veja [**SQLFiddle** para `UNION`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/597d07/1) e [**SQLFiddle** para `UNION ALL`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/597d07/2).

Existem casos que pode complicar. Se por exemplo tiver uma coluna `UNIQUE`, incluindo aí a `PRIMARY KEY`, pode não dar o resultado esperado, então nesses casos uma coluna assim não deveria fazer parte do `SELECT`. [Veja no **SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad5d03/1).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Union.sql).

Comment: Acho que vale a pena citar que, devido a ser indiferente com resultados idênticos, `UNION ALL` é mais rápido. Também tem o caso de, pelo menos no SQLServer que eu testei, o `UNION ALL` começa a retornar resultados parciais mais rapidamente (portanto, maior disponibilidade)

Answer (score 12):

Uma outra alternativa de como ver `UNION` e `UNION ALL` vem diretamente da matemática:

- `UNION` é uma operação de coleções de elementos que resulta em um terceiro **conjunto**;
- `UNION ALL` é uma operação de coleções de elementos resultando em uma ***bag***.

Aqui, tanto **conjunto** como ***bag*** são **coleções de elementos**. A diferença entre eles é dada pela "operação de **soma**" de elementos a uma coleção pré-existente. Vou definir como "soma":

```
el + C = R
```

Onde `el` é um elemento qualquer, `C` é a coleção pré-existente e `R` é a coleção resultante da operação, que contém em sua totalidade `C` e também tem como elemento `el`.

Se `el` não existir previamente em `C`, então as operações com conjunto e *bag* são idênticas. Agora, se `el` já existir previamente em `C`, a soma com um conjunto resultará em `R == C`, não afetando o resultante. Porém a *bag* é alterada com a adição de `el`, portanto `R != C`.

De certo modo, podemos dizer que a *bag* é uma coleção de elementos que admite repetição, já conjunto não admite repetição.

Com isso, temos resultados interessantes ao se usar `UNION` e `UNION ALL`. Como conjunto não admite repetição, o `UNION` comparará todas as tuplas e retornará apenas as únicas. Por uma questão de performance, a primeira operação a ser realizada será uma ordenação total das tuplas (tempo `o(n log n)`) para então eliminar as repetições (tempo `o(n)`). Se ele não fizesse essa ordenação antes da verificação dos únicos, teria um tempo de execução quadrático. Trato exatamente desse problema [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236518/64969), onde expliquei de onde essas ordens de complexidade vem. Também demonstrei lá que toda tupla composta de elementos ordenáveis também pode ser ordenada. Normalmente se trabalha com números, strings e datas em um banco de dados, então nesse conjunto universo é possível obter uma ordenação. Pôde-se também usar uma heurística para ordenação de blobs, tratando-os como uma palavra de bytes e ordená-los lexicograficamente, mantendo portanto uma ordenação mais "natural". Para o caso de enumerações, como elas possuem rótulos em strings, poderíamos usar esses rótulos e continuar com uma ordenação no conjunto (embora essa ordenação agora não seja mais uma ordenação natural).

Então, por questão de performance, ao requisitar um `UNION`, normalmente o SGBD guardará todo o resultado da consulta, executará uma única ordenação no final de tudo e então obterá o resultado de tuplas únicas. Ele não faz ordenamentos parciais do conjunto de dados pois é extremamente ruim para a performance; executar uma ordenação a cada `m` dados novos significa rodar `o(n/m)` vezes uma ordenação de `o(n log n)`, o que pode acabar ficando pior até mesmo que uma ordenação quadrática se `m` for mal escolhido.

Isso tudo implica que `UNION` não tem alta **disponibilidade**, pois só começará a retornar após obter todos os dados.

Já `UNION ALL`, como tem como resultado uma *bag*, não precisa obter previamente todo o resultado para então devolver. No momento que um resultado é obtido, ele já pode responder imediatamente a quem fez a consulta, esquecer desse valor é pegar o próximo. Isso torna sua **disponibilidade** muito maior. Sem falar que potencialmente, dependendo de como foi implementado o motor de SQL usado, o resultado desse operador não precisa ser armazenado em memória, podendo ser retornado imediatamente para quem o chamou utilizar o dado obtido.

Por ventura, pode-se necessitar de se trabalhar com **conjuntos** propriamente ditos, não com ***bags***, mas nem por isso você precisará usar `UNION`. Claro, isso vai depender extremamente da semântica de cada caso, não recomendo portanto generalizar. Vou dar um exemplo em que é possível obter um conjunto a partir do uso de `UNION ALL`.

Eu tenho [uma modelagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/251136/64969) mais ou menos assim:

[image: [relacionamento via multiplexação, onde uma tabela aponta hipoteticamente para 3 outras a partir de uma chave estrangeira multiplexada pelo valor de outra coluna]]

Eu preciso resgatar o nome e código de todos os correntistas, assim como se ele é "supervisor", "vendedor" ou "cliente". A chave estrangeira em "conta_corrente" é `cd_usuario`, que por sua vez se liga com `cd_cliente`, ou `cd_vendedor`, ou `cd_supervisor`, dependendo da muliplexação. No meu caso, cada correntista só pode ter no máximo uma conta corrente. A consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT cd_usuario, "cliente" AS tp_correntista, nm_cliente AS nm_correntista
FROM conta_corrente cc INNER JOIN
    cliente c ON (c.cd_cliente = cc.cd_usuario)
WHERE cc.tp_conta = 'c'
UNION
SELECT cd_usuario, "vendedor" AS tp_correntista, nm_vendedor AS nm_correntista
FROM conta_corrente cc INNER JOIN
    vendedor v ON (v.cd_vendedor = cc.cd_usuario)
WHERE cc.tp_conta = 'v'
UNION
SELECT cd_usuario, "supervisor" AS tp_correntista, nm_supervisor AS nm_correntista
FROM conta_corrente cc INNER JOIN
    supervisor s ON (s.cd_supervisor = cc.cd_usuario)
WHERE cc.tp_conta = 's'
```

Pronto, a consulta retorna um conjunto como esperado. Agora, notou como não é possível que, por acaso, haja uma igualdade de tuplas entre, digamos, a primeira consulta e a segunda consulta? Isso porque todos os elementos da primeira consulta terão como segundo elemento de suas tuplas o valor "cliente", já os da segunda consulta o valor na mesma posição seria "vendedor". Além disso, como `cd_cliente` é chave primária da tabela `cliente` e cada `cliente` nesse modelo só está atrelado a no máximo um elemento da tabela `conta_corrente`, então não tem choque de tuplas dentro de cada consulta individual, portanto cada uma das 3 consultas acima resulta num conjunto.

Como já temos 3 conjuntos, e temos garantia que nenhum desses conjuntos tem elemento em comum com outro conjunto, a operação de "soma" terá o mesmo resultado final que a "soma" de *bags*. Portanto, em casos assim, o uso do `UNION ALL` garante o resultado desejado e também garante uma melhor performance (teoricamente pelo menos).

A consulta então pode ser reescrita assim:

```
SELECT cd_usuario, "cliente" AS tp_correntista, nm_cliente AS nm_correntista
FROM conta_corrente cc INNER JOIN
    cliente c ON (c.cd_cliente = cc.cd_usuario)
WHERE cc.tp_conta = 'c'
UNION ALL
SELECT cd_usuario, "vendedor" AS tp_correntista, nm_vendedor AS nm_correntista
FROM conta_corrente cc INNER JOIN
    vendedor v ON (v.cd_vendedor = cc.cd_usuario)
WHERE cc.tp_conta = 'v'
UNION ALL
SELECT cd_usuario, "supervisor" AS tp_correntista, nm_supervisor AS nm_correntista
FROM conta_corrente cc INNER JOIN
    supervisor s ON (s.cd_supervisor = cc.cd_usuario)
WHERE cc.tp_conta = 's'
```

Comment: Parabéns! Difícil encontrar uma resposta, ainda mais em nossa língua, com tal grau de preocupação com a precisão matemática.