# Select Aninhado

Tags: sql

Preciso desenvolver uma tela que mostre os TOP 50 cardápios mais acessados. Dizer o número de acessos e a que cidade pertence. Ordenar por número de acessos e selecionar valores referentes aos últimos 30 dias.

Para resolver a primeira situação tenho esse comando:

```
SELECT
    menu. NAME AS Nome,
    city. NAME AS Cidade,
    count(*) AS qtdAcessos
FROM
    history.view_menu
JOIN menu ON menu.menu_id = view_menu.menu_id
JOIN address ON address.address_id = menu.address_id
JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
GROUP BY
    menu. NAME,
    city. NAME
ORDER BY
    qtdAcessos DESC
LIMIT 50
```

E o seguinte comando é para devolver os valores referentes aos ultimos 30 dias:

```
SELECT
    view_menu. CURRENT_DATE
FROM
    history.view_menu
WHERE
    view_menu. CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 30
AND CURRENT_DATE
```

Minha dúvida é: como juntar esses dois comandos?

Comment: Poste também a estrutura das tabelas, por favor.

Comment: history_menu(view_manu_id current_date menu_id people_id)

Comment: Em uma rápida olhada seu where da ultima query esta errado. WHERE view_menu. CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 30 AND CURRENT_DATE

Comment: Outra coisa não só bastaria por esse where na primeira query?

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso a única coisa que você precisa fazer é adicionar o seu where na primeira sentença, no seu caso ficaria assim

```
SELECT
    menu. NAME AS Nome,
    city. NAME AS Cidade,
    count(*) AS qtdAcessos
FROM
    history.view_menu
    JOIN menu ON menu.menu_id = view_menu.menu_id
    JOIN address ON address.address_id = menu.address_id
    JOIN city ON city.city_id = address.city_id
WHERE view_menu.CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 30
    AND CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY
    menu. NAME,
    city. NAME
ORDER BY
    qtdAcessos DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Para consultar informações pertencentes a mais de uma tabela e que são obtidas com a execução de mais de um comando `SELECT`, devemos usar a cláusula `UNION ALL`, que facilita a exibição de dados de tabelas distintas.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Você pode usar o `UNION` ou `UNION ALL`. `UNION` não combinará linhas das demais tabelas combinadas que já existam no resultado das consultas aplicadas nas tabelas anteriores. `UNION ALL` não se importará com isso. Veja nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153498/51124) a explicação completa sobre a diferença entre eles.