# Como juntar 2 select no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Tenho 2 select que são basicamente idênticos, mudando apenas 1 tabela. Estou tentando juntar os 2 em um único select, mas não estou conseguindo.

Segue os select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            a.id,
            a.unidade,
            a.posicao,
            a.nome,
            a.peso
        FROM
            produtos a,
            produtos_pedidos b
        WHERE
            a.id = b.id_produto
            and b.id_pedido IN (1,2)
        ORDER BY a.nome
```

Select 2:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
            a.id,
            a.unidade,
            a.posicao,
            a.nome,
            a.peso
        FROM
            produtos a,
            pedidos_barganha b
        WHERE
            a.id = b.id_produto
            and b.id_pedido IN (1,2)
        ORDER BY a.nome
```

Alguém sabe como posso juntar os 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você terá que usar o operador `UNION` entre eles, no seu caso ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    a.unidade,
    a.posicao,
    a.nome,
    a.peso
FROM
    produtos a,
    produtos_pedidos b
WHERE
    a.id = b.id_produto
    and b.id_pedido IN (1,2)

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    p.id,
    p.unidade,
    p.posicao,
    p.nome,
    p.peso
FROM
    produtos p,
    pedidos_barganha pb
WHERE
    p.id = pb.id_produto
    and pb.id_pedido IN (1,2)
ORDER BY nome
```

Vale observar que caso você utilize o `UNION` o `Order BY` deve ser escrito somente ao final de toda sua consulta.

Além do `UNION`, você também pode utilizar o `UNION ALL` nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153498/26133) você pode ver a diferença entre eles e escolher o que irá te atender melhor

Comment: Deu o seguinte erro #1250 - Tabela 'a' de um dos SELECTs não pode ser usada em field list

Comment: @HugoBorges editei a resposta, vc poderia testar?

Comment: agora esta assim #1250 - Tabela 'p' de um dos SELECTs não pode ser usada em field list

Comment: achei o erro, é so mudar o ' ORDER BY
        nome'

Comment: @HugoBorges corrigir isso e adicionei mais uma informação no final

Answer (score 3):

Usa o UNION.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.id,
    a.unidade,
    a.posicao,
    a.nome,
    a.peso
FROM
    produtos a,
    produtos_pedidos b
WHERE
    a.id = b.id_produto
AND b.id_pedido IN (1, 2)
UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT
        c.id,
        c.unidade,
        c.posicao,
        c.nome,
        c.peso
    FROM
        produtos c,
        pedidos_barganha d
    WHERE
        c.id = d.id_produto
    AND d.id_pedido IN (1, 2)
    ORDER BY
        c.nome
```

Comment: Bom da sua forma deu o seguinte erro, #1221 - Uso errado de UNION e ORDER BY

Comment: Verdade. Tirei o `order by` do primeiro SELECT.

Comment: o erro mudou para #1250 - Tabela 'a' de um dos SELECTs não pode ser usada em field list