# Existe uma maneira de juntar 2 queries de tabelas distintas em uma única query?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de juntar 2 queries de tabelas distintas em uma única query?

Por exemplo, no código abaixo tenho 2 consultas em tabelas distintas. Entretanto, existe uma maneira de realizar essas 2 consultas como uma única, de uma vez só, em vez de ter que fazer 2 variáveis e duas consultas separadas?

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT cod_empresa, razao_social FROM tbl_empresa ORDER by razao_social ASC") or die(mysql_error());
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT cod_tipo, tipo_publicacao FROM tbl_tipo_publicacao by tipo_publicacao ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Veja: [Qual é a diferença entre UNION e UNION ALL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153496/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-union-e-union-all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a instrução `UNION`, mas precisa que o número e os tipos das colunas resultadas sejam iguais em ambas as consultas.

Ex:

```
SELECT id, nome FROM alunos
UNION
SELECT id, nome FROM professores
```

Os nomes das colunas não precisam ser iguais.

---

[A documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) explica o uso do `UNION` em detalhes.