# Como mesclar duas arrays multidimencionais, desprezando valores repetidos?

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho dois *arrays* multidimensionais. Um array eu estou trazendo de um **arquivo .json**, o outro está vindo de um **POST via Ajax**.

A minha ideia é gerar um novo **array** com a fusão desses outros dois outros *arrays* multidimensionais, sem repetir os dados.

Os arrays vindos por POST via Ajax trazem informações de elementos de uma página. O campo 'tempo' é único, já o campo 'vis' pode variar entre os valores 0 e 1 (não visualizado e visualizado).

Esse abaixo é o array vindo do arquivo .json:

```
{"AdministradorGabrielOliveira":
    [
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:00",
            "vis":1
        },
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:04",
            "vis":0
        },
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:05",
            "vis":0
        }
    ]
}
```

E esse abaixo é o array vindo do POST via Ajax:

```
{"AdministradorGabrielOliveira":
    [
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:00",
            "vis":0
        },
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:01",
            "vis":0
        }
    ]
}
```

Ao final, eu deveria ter como resultado da fusão dos dois *arrays*, um outro com o conteúdo:

```
{"AdministradorGabrielOliveira":
    [
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:00",
            "vis":1
        },
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:04",
            "vis":0
        },
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:05",
            "vis":0
        },
        {
            "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:01",
            "vis":0
        }
    ]
}
```

Tentei percorrer os *arrays* dentro de dois *foreach*, mas não tive sucesso. Alguém pode me dar uma dica?

**[EDITADO]** : Segui a dica de vocês e mudei a estrutura para o user comportar os valores 'tempo' e 'vis', com 'tempo' como sendo o id.

Comment: Existe alguma razão para você não usar o valor de `user` como chave do elemento? Uma chave por user e dentro do elemento user, uma chave por `tempo` que teria o valor de `vis`. Isso facilitaria bastante seu trabalho.

Comment: Seguindo a sugestão do @ClaydersonFerreira facilitaria até nas coisas que iria fazer a seguir como por exemplo, pegar em todos os tempos de um user e fazer qualquer coisa. No que tem neste momento você teria que iterar a coleção inteira.

Comment: Qual o parâmetro para definir se é igual? Os três valores devem ser idênticos?

Comment: De acordo com a estrutura e descrição do AP presumo que sejam iguais se `user` e `tempo` forem iguais já que o `vis` indica só se foi ou não visualizado

Comment: Na realidade eu tinha pensado nisso só não pus em prática porque o código que desenvolvi estava funcionando no modelo inicial, aí não quis mudar pra não perder o foco. Mas não tinha pensado que isso poderia facilitar tanto as coisas... :/ rsrs boa!

Se entendi bem o que vocês estão propondo, a estrutura de array deveria ficar assim, não é?

 {"user":
  [
   {
    "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:00",
    "vis":0
   },
   {
    "tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:01",
    "vis":0
   }
  ]
 }

Comment: Até sei como mesclar esses Json, porem eu não sei como fazer isso sem repetir os dados.

Comment: O seu problema é semelhante a este outro: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231110/64969; vou tentar subir assim que possível uma adaptação da solução apresentada para a questão que linkei

Comment: Opa! Vou olhar direitinho as dicas quando chegar em ksa. Mas desde já, muito obrigado!

Comment: E sim. vou passar a usar o  'user' como array principal, e 'tempo' como id, para eu pesquisar só na coleção que realmente preciso. Valeu pela dica pessoal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este código remove todos os valores repetidos.

```
<?php
$entrada1 = '{"forum":[{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:00","vis":1},{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:22","vis":1},{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:04","vis":0},{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:05","vis":0}]}';
$entrada2 = '{"forum":[{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:00","vis":1},{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:04","vis":0},{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:05","vis":0},{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"2017-08-24T04:57:13-03:01","vis":0}]}';

$json1 = json_decode($entrada1);
$json2 = json_decode($entrada2);

foreach($json1->forum as $indice => $f1){
    foreach($json2->forum as $f2){
        if(!isset($f1) || !isset($f2)){
            continue;
        }
        $f1_string = json_encode($f1);
        $f2_string = json_encode($f2);
        if ($f1->user == $f2->user && $f1->tempo == $f2->tempo){
            unset($json1->forum[$indice]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou testar nesse exato momento, meu caro!

Comment: Seu código está ótimo, brother! Só tem aquele detalhe que até agora não consegui resolver. Seguinte, os valores de $entrada1 são recebidos dum site como sendo o feedback de uma postagem clicada, então, se eu tiver na $entrada1 o 'tempo'='x1' e 'vis'=1 , e na $entrada2 o 'tempo'='x1' e 'vis'=0 , eu devo mesclar as duas considerando que a posição que contém 'tempo'='x1', tanto em $entrada1 quanto em $entrada2, isso devem resultar em $entrada1 = '{"forum":[{"user":"AdministradorGabrielOliveira","tempo":"x1","vis":1}]}';

Comment: Fiz uma alteração, agora ele compara o "user" e o "tempo", então se o "user" e o "tempo" for igual ele remove o item da "entrada1". Assim fica mais fácil para você decidir o que você quer comparar.

Comment: Essa solução é quadrática. Se o tamanho da entrada poder explodir (por exemplo, alguns milhões de dados), então o tempo de execução dela se torna inviável. Se você tem a garantia de que ela é de tamanho controlado (talvez até alguns milhares de dados?), essa preocupação que falei anteriormente é purismo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Só vejo uma solução não quadrática para o algoritmo, que é utilizar chaves especificas em ambos os arrays, o que torna O(n). Mas implica pré processamento de ambas as estruturas de entrada.

Comment: @Isac sim, com pré processamento mesmo. Imaginei aqui uma solução usando ordenação, o que reduziria para `o(b log n + n)`. A parte linearítma para o pré processamento, mais `o(n)` da busca

Comment: Opa! **Muito obrigado @WictorChaves e todos que ajudaram!** Esse script está ótimo pra o que preciso. Realmente Jefferson e Isac, existe a questão do excesso de processamento desses dados, mas não será problema para o que tenho. Os dados que irei analisar, tanto os que virão da página quanto os que virão do arquivo, são relativamente pequenos pq a página mesmo exclui as notificações de postagens com um certo tempo, então nem precisarei guardar dados antigos por muito tempo. Vou ainda, colocar um limite no tamanho do array. Mas de novo, obrigadão pela colaboração, pessoal. Ajudou pra caramba!!!

Comment: @GabrielOliveira marque esta resposta como resposta da sua pergunta, por favor.

Comment: Verdade... Feito!

Answer (score 4):

A [solução do @WictorChaves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236564/64969) é suficiente para a questão, dado o tamanho dos dados. A solução que proponho abaixo é *overkill*, com uma entrada algumas ordens de grandeza acima do que está sendo utilizado para o caso da questão atual.

---

Teve uma [pergunta que respondi recentemente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/231110/64969) que precisava de performance para julgar a interseção entre dois conjuntos em C#. Ele usava um algoritmo quadrático `o(n * m)` para determinar a interseção. Na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236518/64969), fiz um preâmbulo teórico mostrando que é possível resolver o problema em tempo linearítmico (aproximadamente `o(n log n)`).

Bem, a questão lá tratava de calcular a interseção, mas essa aqui trata de calcular a união. Aqui, está sendo feito uma união matemática de conjuntos propriamente dita, por isso o comportamento de *eliminar as duplicações*.

Na união de conjuntos, acontece o seguinte:

[image: {a, b, c} união {b, c, d} gera {a, b, c, d}]

Para fazer a operação de união desse jeito, também é necessário remover os valores idênticos.

Se os conjuntos estão desordenados, precisamos comparar todos os valores de um conjunto com os do outro conjunto. Portanto, tempo quadrático `o(n * m)`.

Porém, se os conjuntos estiverem ordenados, a identificação dos termos idênticos precisa de tempo linear `o(n + m)`. Na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236518/64969), sugeri um algoritmo para identificar os elementos da interseção. Vou apresentar uma versão ligeiramente modificada dele.

- `A`, um conjunto ordenado de elementos do tipo `E`
- `B`, um conjunto ordenado de elementos do tipo `E`
- `cmp : E,E -> S`, uma função que, dados dois elementos de `E`, define qual a relação entre eles; retorna `-` caso o primeiro elemento seja menor do que o segundo; `+` se o primeiro elemento for maior do que o segundo ou `0` caso os elementos sejam idênticos (`S` é o conjunto sinal: `{-, 0, +}`)

  ```
  entrada:
    A, conjunto ordenado de elementos do tipo E
    B, conjunto ordenado de elementos do tipo E
    cmp, função sinal que compara dois elementos de E
  retorno:
    C, conjunto de elementos do tipo E oriundo da união de A e B

  começo
    i <- 0 # índice para iterar em A
    j <- 0 # índice para iterar em B
    C <- []
    ultimo_elemento_adicionado <- null

    enquanto i < A.tamanho && j < B.tamanho:
      s = cmp(A[i], B[j])
      se s == '0':
        # elementos são iguais, um deles como elemento candidato
        candidato <- A[i]
        i <- i + 1
        j <- j + 1
      senão, se s == '-':
        # A[i] < B[j], então próxima comparação será com A[i + 1] e B[j]; A[i] agora é candidato
        candidato <- A[i]
        i <- i + 1
      senão # caso trivial onde s == '+':
        # A[i] > B[j], então próxima comparação será com A[i] e B[j + 1]; B[j] agora é candidato
        candidato <- B[j]
        j <- j + 1
      # agora vamos ver se o candidato deve ser inserido em C: precisa ser distinto do último elemento adicionado, ou ser o primeiro elemento adicionado
      se ultimo_elemento_adicionado != null && cmp(candidato, ultimo_elemento_adicionado) != '0':
          ultimo_elemento_adicionado = candidato
          C.push(candidato)
    # caso i ou j extrapolem o tamanho de A ou B, respectivamente, não há mais comparações a se fazer
    retorna C
  fim
  ```

Ao todo, há a garantia que a busca demore `o(n + m)` operações. Tempo linear, fazendo com que seu problema torne-se tangível agora.

Em compensação, para poder fazer esse algoritmo de tempo linear, precisamos pré processar os conjuntos de dados `A` e `B`, [conforme reparado pelo @Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236533/como-mesclar-duas-arrays-multidimencionais-desprezando-valores-repetidos/236564?noredirect=1#comment484458_236564). Conforme expliquei [na resposta em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236518/64969), é possível fazer uma ordenação total em qualquer conjunto de elementos compostos, contanto que cada uma das chaves desses elementos seja passível de ordenação total.

Então, desenvolvendo a função `cmp` que estabelece relação de ordenação total entre os elementos desejados no seu conjunto de elementos, você consegue fazerordenar os elemento em `o(n log n)` e então aplicar o algoritmo acima e obter a união.

Para transformar o JSON em objetos PHP, você pode usar a função [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php). No caso, depois de decodificar o JSON, basta ordenar usando a função `cmp` de ordenação total do campo o array dentro do objeto decodificado `$json_decodificado->AdministradorGabrielOliveira`.

Comment: Respondendo a [uma pergunta sobre complexidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237026/64969), percebi que cometi um pequeno erro na operação de união. Falta terminar de percorrer os elementos restantes dos conjuntos `A` e `B` quando o `while` termina para os conjuntos `B` e `A` respectivamente

Comment: Nossa! Muito obrigado mesmo pelo esclarecimento @JeffersonQuesado .  Confesso que estava desenvolvendo sem pensar tanto na questão do peso desse processamento. Vou me atentar mais pra esse "detalhe".

Comment: @GabrielOliveira , pro seu caso, com quantidade controlada, não precisa se preocupar demais