# Como provar a ordem assintótica de um algoritmo?

Tags: algoritmo, matemática, complexidade-de-algoritmo, ciência-da-computação

Considerando um algoritmo como o abaixo:

```js
function somaMatriz(matA, size) {
  let soma = 0;                                        // 1
  for(let i = 0; i < size; i++){                       // n + 1
    for(let j = 0; j < size; j++){                     // n(n + 1)
      soma += a[i][j];                                 // (n.n)
    }
  }  
  return soma;                                         // 1 
}
```

Numa análise um pouco detalhada — considerando custo unitário e uniforme — a expressão referente ao custo seria algo como:

> *T(n) = 3 + 2n + 2n²*

No entanto, pode-se notar facilmente que **T(n)** pertence a **O(n²)**.

Eu sei que a ordem assintótica não quer dizer **literalmente** que esta função (neste caso, **`n²`**) domina a função original (neste caso, **`3 + 2n + 2n²`**), mas sim que existem uma constante — que chamarei de **c** — e um valor "inicial" de **n** —
 que chamarei de **m** — tais que:

<sup>*Considerando **n²** como **f(n)** e **3 + 2n + 2n²** como **g(n)***.</sup>

> ***cf(n)*** domine assintoticamente ***g(n)*** a partir de um determinado **m**.

No caso do exemplo, pode-se ver isso bem facilmente. Tomando **c** como **3** e **m** como **4**, tem-se:

> *3 + 2 * 4 + 2 * 4²* = **43**

e

> *3 * 4²* = **48**

E, a partir disto (**n ≥ 4**), para qualquer possível valor de **n** a função **cf(n)** domina **g(n)**.

Mas como isso pode ser provado matematicamente? No caso acima, por exemplo, fiz na tentativa e erro (e depois conferi nos exemplos de um livro).

Por exemplo, até pra tentar padronizar as possíveis respostas, como provar que:

> **5n² + 3n ∈ O(n²)**

Comment: A notação grande `O` representa conjuntos. Usamos sinal de igualdade por vicio. O correto seria dizer `n^2 + n pertence a O(n^2)`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Eu acabei achando o sinal de "pertence" meio feio pra quando coloquei ali, aí troquei pelo sinal de igualdade xD

Comment: são os vícios de linguagem. E sinceramente fica muito mais bonito com = e todo mundo entende, então é um vício perdoável

Comment: `lim(n->inf, 5n2+3n)=lim(n->inf, n(5n+3))` 3 é desprezável face a 5n portanto `...=lim(n->inf, 5n2)=5*lim(n->inf, n2)` ==>  ...O(n2)

Comment: `5n^2+3n <= 5n^2+3n^2` => `5n^2 + 3n <= 8n^2` que daria um k de `8`, logo `an^2 + bn <= an^2 + bn^2` => `an^2 + bn <= (a+b)n^2`, o que implica que um `k` de `a+b` funciona sempre. Era isso que tava a tentar obter?

Comment: @Isac eu fiquei confuso; `=>` é realmente uma seta, correto?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim uma seta de implicação(implica que), para dar seguimento a equação. Normalmente seria o `<=>` de equivalente, mas saiu me assim

Comment: @Isac certo, é que essa ruma de igual me deixou confuso

Comment: @Isac É isso. Exatamente neste caminho.

Comment: @Isac , eu mostrei a pertinência a um conjunto grande O por divisão de função. Particularmente é a formalização disso que você escreveu. Sem falar que assim considera que `o(n) = o(n^2)` mas que `o(n^2) =/= o(n)`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, a sua resposta é muito boa e abrange o que eu disse formalmente, apenas estava a dar um calculo possível e curto para o `k` (que na pergunta está indicado como `m`) numa equação do tipo `an^2+bn`

Comment: Jefferson deu uma resposta muito completa. Na verdade, é muito simples. Para provar, é só calcular o limite. Por que não houve seleção da resposta? Devo tentar explicar também para ver se ele entende?

Comment: @RHERWOLF Tentar explicar pra ver se quem entende?

Comment: Você. Aqui diz que você não marcou nenhuma resposta, então ainda não foi esclarecido, né? Estou vendo uma explicação mais direta para postar, pode ser mais adequada.

Comment: @RHERWOLF na verdade isso quer dizer que eu ainda não decidi qual resposta vai ser escolhida e estou aceitando novas respostas. Fique a vontade.

Comment: @LINQ ok, as respostas daí são suficientes, bem completas.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Vou dar uma resposta curta e referente apenas á prova, apesar de o Jefferson já ter falado (e muito bem) de complexidades, domínios, notações associadas, etc.

**Provar que uma função `c.g(n)` domina `f(n)` a partir de um determinado `n` e `c`.**

Sendo `f(n)` uma função quadrática como o exemplo dado, `5n^2 + 3n`, podemos formalmente defini-la como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então sabemos que ela será sempre igual ou inferior a:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Logo podemos transformar numa inequação e ir manipulando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por isso temos a certeza que a partir de um `c` de `A+B+C` a função `c.g(n)` domina `f(n)` para todo o `n >= 1`.

Pegando no `5n² + 3n` de exemplo e aplicando a lógica temos a certeza que um `c` de `8`, vindo de  `(5+3+0)`, é suficiente para dominar a função, o que não implica que não haja um `c` mais baixo que também a domine!

**Provar que `f(n)` que pertence ao conjunto de `O(g(n))`**

Neste caso temos que usar a formula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em que irá pertencer ao conjunto se `c` for um número real finito maior ou igual a `0`.

Aplicando ao mesmo exemplo, e tomando `f(n)` como `5n² + 3n` e `g(n)` como `n²` temos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como `c` é `5`, prova que `5n² + 3n` pertence a `O(n²)`

Podemos ainda generalizar esta prova para qualquer função quadrática, na forma de [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como `a` é um coeficiente, logo uma constante, automaticamente prova que todas as funções quadráticas pertencem a `O(n²)` a menos que este seja negativo, o que para uma analise de complexidade de um algoritmo não poderá ser.

Ambas as provas podem naturalmente ser extrapoladas para funções que não sejam quadráticas, generalizando uma solução para esse tipo de funções.

Comment: Elegante método para fazer a inequação de polinômios com x->infinito

Answer (score 21):

A complexidade de algoritmos é dado por uma função. Quando estamos tratando de problemas clássicos não recursivos, normalmente nos deparamos com polinômios.

> [TL;DR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237177/64969), a resposta do @Isac mostra de modo muito elegante os resultados necessários
>
> [TL;DR2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240165/64969), ótima resposta com ótimo rigor matemático sobre a pertinência de função à sua ordem de complexidade

Como dito no comentário, a notação grande `O` define conjuntos. Então, quando falamos que `n^2 + n = O(n^2)`, estamos dizendo que a função `n^2 + n` pertence ao conjunto `O(n^2)`. Quando dizemos que `O(n^2) = O(n^3)` estamos dizendo que o conjunto `O(n^2)` está contido em `O(n^3)`; note que essa operação não é comutativa, pois não é a igualdade tradicional, então, apesar de `O(n^2) = O(n^3)` ser verdade, `O(n^3) = O(n^2)` é falso.

Ok, agora como definimos a pertinência de uma função a um conjunto descrito por notação grande `O`? Fazendo uma divisão de função levando ao limite do infinito (literalmente, volto nesse ponto mais tarde).

Você deve ter percebido que a notação grande `O` é sempre acompanhada de uma função, certo? Como `O(n log n)`, `O(n)`, `O(n^2)`, `O(e^n)`, `O(n^3 + n)`. A função dentro do parênteses representa seu comportamento; <s>não achei um nome formal, mas podemos chamar essa função de **assinatura do conjunto**.</s> o nome para essa função é **função limitante** (informação cortesia do @LINQ).

Para determinar se uma função `f(x)` pertence ao conjunto `O(g(n))`, precisamos saber se `f(x)` domina a <s>função de assinatura</s> função limitante do conjunto `g(x)`; se `f(x)` dominar `g(x)`, então `f(x)` não pertence a `O(g(x))`, pertence ao seu conjunto complementar `omega(g(x))`.

> Notação `omega`: na notação grande `O`, definimos quais funções tem comportamento assintótico máximo igual à <s>assinatura</s> limitante do conjunto, na notação `omega`, definimos quais funções tem comportamento assintótico mínimo igual à <s>assinatura</s> do conjunto; por exemplo, insertion sort funciona em `omega(n)` (conjunto previamente ordenado ou pouco bagunçado) mas merge sort funciona em `omega(n log n)`
>
> Notação `theta`: se `f(x) = O(g(x))` e `f(x) = omega(g(x))`, então `f(x) = theta(g(x))`; a notação `theta` estabelece comportamentos assintóticos mínimo e máximo ao mesmo tempo; por exemplo, bubble sort sem otimização funciona em `theta(n^2)`.

Então, agora precisamos definir a operação de dominação entre funções. Vou chamar essa função de `domina(f, g)`, ele recebe duas funções e retorna um de três resultados possíveis:

- `dominada` se `f` for dominada por `g`;
- `co-dominantes` se não é possível definir quem domina quem;
- `dominante` se `f` dominar `g`.

A função `domina(f,g)` é descrita assim:

[image: domina(f,g) usando divisão de funções]

---

Pronto, agora sabemos dizer definir quando uma função `f(x)` pertence a um grupo `O(g(x))`, mas isso ainda não é suficiente para provar se dado algoritmo executa nessa ordem de complexidade. Para saber isso, é necessário saber mais ou menos quantas operações serão necessárias fazer para o algoritmo funcionar.

Definir quantidades de operações depende da máquina que vai executar o algoritmo. Por exemplo, um x86 tem como uma operação unitária somar dois números de 16 bits `n` e `m` retornando outro número de 16 bits fazendo uma soma em `O(1)`; uma máquina de Turing simples usando notação unária não consegue fazer a soma em um termo constante de operações, mas precisaria fazer `O(n + m)` operações para concluir o processamento.

Então, sim, `soma(n, m) = O(1)` em processadores x86 com `n` e `m` com tamanho fixo de 16 bits, mas `soma(n, m) = O(n + m)` numa máquina de Turing. (Nota: na máquina de Turing, não estamos limitando os valores de `n` nem de `m`).

Normalmente, operações aritméticas básicas (como soma, multiplicação e divisão) com números palpáveis são feitas em bitagem fixa e consideramos elas com peso `O(1)`.

> Pequena demonstração informal: `b` é constante, portanto `O(1)`; `n` é limitado por `b` dígitos, tendo tamanho `O(b)`; a soma usando números binários é feita analisando cada bit de `n` e de `m` uma única vez, junto a uma variável auxiliar, portanto a máquina de Turing vai passar por todos os bits apenas uma vez, logo `O(tamanho(n) + tamanho(m))`; como o tamanho é limitado a `O(b)`, `O(tamanho(n) + tamanho(m)) = O(O(b) + O(b)) = O(b + b) = O(2b) = O(b) = O(1)`.

Em casos não recursivos (nem direta nem indiretamente), basta verificar os laços para saber quantas operações são feitas. Vamos analisar o seu caso:

```
function somaMatriz(matA, size)
  let soma = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
      soma += a[i][j];
    }
  }
  return soma;
}
```

Podemos destrinchar essa função em duas e ter o mesmo comportamento assintótico:

```
function somaLinha(matA, size, i) {
  let soma = 0;
  for(let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    soma += a[i][j];
  }
  return soma;
}

function somaMatriz(matA, size) {
  let soma = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    soma += somaLinha(matA, size, i);
  }
  return soma;
}
```

Isso quer dizer que `somaMatriz(matA,size)` vai fazer `O(size*O(somaLinha(matA,size,i)) + 2)` operações; `size * O(somaLinha(matA,size,i))` porque o laço externo se repete `size` vezes (`i` de `[0,size)` é `O(size)`) fazendo a operação `somaLinha(matA,size,i)` cada vez. O `2` que aparece é devido ao retorno e a inicialização, porém sabemos que qualquer função crescente domina um valor constante, então esse `2` acaba saindo da assinatura.

Muito bem, para definir agora o custo de `somaLinha(matA,size,i)` podemos dividir ela em duas partes (de modo análogo a o que acabamos de fazer com `somaMatriz(matA, size)`):

```
function operador_soma(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function somaLinha(matA, size, i) {
  let soma = 0;
  for(let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
    soma = operador_soma(soma, a[i][j]);
  }
  return soma;
}
```

De modo análogo, `somaLinha(matA, size, i)` vai fazer `O(size)` operações de `operador_soma`. `operador_soma` é só uma simples soma de números razoáveis e de bitagem fixa, então executa em `O(1)`. Portanto, `somaLinha(matA, size, i) = O(size * operador_soma) = O(size * O(1)) = O(size)`.

Substituindo esse resultado no comportamento assintótico de `somaMatriz`, temos que `O(simaMatriz,matA,size) = O(size*O(somaLinha(matA,size,i)) + 2) = O(size*O(O(size)) + 2) = O(size * size) = O(size ^2)`.

---

Quando o laço não tem um tamanho muito 100% definido de maneira óbvia, a análise é um pouco mais complicada.

Tome como exemplo a função que faz a união entre dois conjuntos ordenados (baseada na função [dessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236929/64969):

```
entrada:
  A, conjunto ordenado de elementos do tipo E
  B, conjunto ordenado de elementos do tipo E
  cmp, função sinal que compara dois elementos de E
retorno:
  C, conjunto de elementos do tipo E oriundo da união de A e B

começo
  i <- 0 # índice para iterar em A
  j <- 0 # índice para iterar em B
  C <- []
  ultimo_elemento_adicionado <- null

  enquanto i < A.tamanho && j < B.tamanho:
    s = cmp(A[i], B[j])
    se s == '0':
      # elementos são iguais, um deles como elemento candidato
      candidato <- A[i]
      i <- i + 1
      j <- j + 1
    senão, se s == '-':
      # A[i] < B[j], então próxima comparação será com A[i + 1] e B[j]; A[i] agora é candidato
      candidato <- A[i]
      i <- i + 1
    senão # caso trivial onde s == '+':
      # A[i] > B[j], então próxima comparação será com A[i] e B[j + 1]; B[j] agora é candidato
      candidato <- B[j]
      j <- j + 1
    # agora vamos ver se o candidato deve ser inserido em C: precisa ser distinto do último elemento adicionado, ou ser o primeiro elemento adicionado
    se ultimo_elemento_adicionado != null && cmp(candidato, ultimo_elemento_adicionado) != '0':
        ultimo_elemento_adicionado = candidato
        C.push(candidato)
  # caso i ou j extrapolem o tamanho de A ou B, respectivamente, não há mais comparações a se fazer
  retorna C
fim
```

Considerando que as operações de `cmp` são executadas em tempo constante `O(1)` e que adicionar um elemento no final de um conjunto indexado também é feito em `O(1)`.

A condição de parada é quando `i` alcança o tamanho de `A` ou quando `j` alcança o tamanho de `B`. Para iteração do laço, obtemos que `i` ou `j` (ou inclusivo) são incrementados. Isso significa que, para parar pela condição de `i >= A.tamanho`, serão necessárias `A.tamanho` operações de incremento em `i`; enquanto isso, para parar pela condição de `j >= B.tamanho`, serão necessárias `B.tamanho` operações de incremento em `j`. Como cada iteração eu garanto que haja pelo menos um incremento, o máximo de iterações feitas é `(A.tamanho - 1) + (B.tamanho - 1) + 1`, portanto esse laço precisa de `O(A.tamanho + B.tamanho)` operações para ser executado.

---

No caso do merge sort, temos uma função recursiva. Sua análise é ainda mais complicada, então não vou me preocupar no formalismo dela, mas em passar a ideia geral.

Revisando o merge sort:

```
mergeSort(E[] entradaDesordenada, E[] areaTrabalho, int ini, int end) {
    if (end - ini <= 1) {
        return;
    }

    int middle = (ini + end) / 2;
    mergeSort(areaTrabalho, entradaDesordenada, ini, middle);
    mergeSort(areaTrabalho, entradaDesordenada, middle, end);
    merge(entradaDesordenada, areaTrabalho, ini, middle, end);
}
```

A ideia do `merge` é juntar dois conjuntos ordenados em um terceiro conjunto ordenado. O grosso do algoritmo é muito parecido com o algoritmo da união que apresentei anteriormente, tendo inclusive o mesmo comportamento. Portanto, `merge(A) = O(tamanho(A))`; se chamarmos `tamanho(A) = n`, temos que a complexidade de `merge = O(n)`.

Então, só falta definir quantas vezes `merge` vai ser chamado. A recursão `mergeSort` é feita de modo que, na chamada recursiva, apenas a metade dos elementos são passadas. Então, a profundidade de chamadas recursivas é `log2(n)`; como `log2(n) = log(n) * log2(10)`, podemos dizer que a profundidade é `O(log n)`. Para cada nível de recursão, `mergeSort` vai ser chamado duas vezes, cada chamada com `n/2` elementos; então cada nível vai chamar `merge` para `n/2` elementos 2 vezes.

A ideia geral pode ser vista nesta imagem:

[image: merge sort pelo link http://rosalind.info/problems/ms/]

Note que em cada nível executamos diversas vezes o `merge` (uma execução para cada nó da árvore). Ao todo, a quantidade de elementos passíveis de merge, em um mesmo nível de profundidade da recursão, é `n`. Portanto, ao todo temos que vão ser feitas `O(profundidade da recursão * n)` operações. Como a profundidade é `O(log n)`, a quantidade de operações é `O(n log n)`.

---

Qual a relevância disso na vida prática? Bem, fiz um experimento para responder a uma pergunta sobre performance de algoritmos de ordenação. Você pode verificar os resultados [na resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/235636/64969). A diferença entre um algoritmo de complexidade temporal `O(n log n)` e `O(n^2)` chega a ser duas ordens de grandeza no tempo total para uma entrada com `n=100.000`

Comment: O [@LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/linq) me mostrou que o nome formal para o que apelidei de  **assinatura do conjunto** é função limitante; mais tarde atualizo o texto com essa correção

Answer (score 11):

## A notação Θ

A questão é sempre verificar qual é o termo da equação que domina. Para isso, usamos a notação [image: Theta] (lê-se "téta").

Uma função [image: f(n)] pertenece a uma classe [image: Theta(k(n))] se, e somente se:

> [image: equação]

Ou seja, a função [image: f(n)] pertence a uma classe [image: Theta(k(n))] se, e somente se, a partir de um determinado valor 
[image: n_0], o resultado de [image: f(n)] sempre for maior ou igual ao valor de [image: k(n)] mutiplicado por alguma constante [image: a] maior que zero e menor ou igual ao valor de [image: k(n)] mutiplicado por alguma outra constante [image: b] maior que [image: a].

Por exemplo, seja [image: f(n)=5n²+3n]. Temos que [image: f(n) in Theta(n²)] porque para todo valor de [image: n >= 3], verificamos que [image: 5n²<=5n²+3n<=6n²]. Neste caso, temos que [image: n0 = 3, a = 5, b = 6]. Para comprovar, podemos olhar a tabela:

> ```
> ╔═══╦═════╦══════════╦═════╗
> ║ n ║ 5n² ║ 5n² + 3n ║ 6n² ║
> ╠═══╬═════╬══════════╬═════╣
> ║ 1 ║   5 ║        8 ║   6 ║
> ║ 2 ║  20 ║       26 ║  24 ║
> ║ 3 ║  45 ║       54 ║  54 ║
> ║ 4 ║  80 ║       92 ║  96 ║
> ║ 5 ║ 125 ║      140 ║ 150 ║
> ║ 6 ║ 180 ║      198 ║ 216 ║
> ╚═══╩═════╩══════════╩═════╝
> ```

Nesta tabela vemos que para todo [image: n >= 3], o valor de [image: 5n² + 3n] está entre o valor de [image: 5n²] e de [image: 6n²]. Isso demonstra que [image: f in Theta(n²)].

Como podemos achar os valores de [image: n0], [image: a] e [image: b]? Quaisquer números [image: a] e [image: b] tal que [image: 0 < a <= 5 < b] serviriam. O 5 é o coeficiente do termo de maior grau. Poderíamos utilizar para [image: a] e [image: b] quaisquer valores que satisfizessem essa inequação, tais como 5 e 5.0001, 3 e 10, 0.0001 e 10000. Mas o que fiz foi escolher o coeficiente do termo de maior grau (5) para o [image: a] e somar 1 a ele para obter o [image: b]. Com isso podemos calcular o [image: n_0] da seguinte forma:

> [image: 6n0^2 = 5n0^2 + 3n0]
>   [image: n0^2 = 3n0]
>   [image: n0 = 3]

A fórmula geral é essa:

> [image: b.k(n0) = f(n0)]

Obviamente que isso depende da escolha do valor de [image: b].

Mas até aqui, partimos do pressuposto de que já sabíamos que a classe era [image: Theta(n²))]. Vamos supor que tentássemos com outras classes:

> ```
> ╔═════╦══════════╦══════╦════════╗
> ║   n ║ 5n² + 3n ║ 6n   ║  1000n ║
> ╠═════╬══════════╬══════╬════════╣
> ║   1 ║        8 ║    6 ║   1000 ║
> ║   2 ║       26 ║   12 ║   2000 ║
> ║   3 ║       54 ║   18 ║   3000 ║
> ║   4 ║       92 ║   24 ║   4000 ║
> ║   5 ║      140 ║   30 ║   5000 ║
> ║   6 ║      198 ║   36 ║   6000 ║
> ║ ... ║      ... ║  ... ║    ... ║
> ║ 199 ║   198602 ║ 1194 ║ 199000 ║
> ║ 200 ║   200600 ║ 1200 ║ 200000 ║
> ║ 201 ║   202608 ║ 1206 ║ 201000 ║
> ╚═════╩══════════╩══════╩════════╝
> ```

Observe que o valor de [image: 5n²+3n] sempre ultrapassa o de [image: 6n]. Mesmo se usarmos um coeficiente enorme e fizermos [image: 1000n], temos que para quaisquer valores de [image: n >= 200], o valor de [image: 5n²+3n] é maior. Isso significa que [image: 5n²+3n] ultrapassa o valor de qualquer função linear (mesmo que o coeficiente utilizado seja muito grande), dado um valor de [image: n] suficientemente grande.

Por outro lado, se tentarmos com uma função de grau maior:

> ```
> ╔══════╦═══════════╦═══════════════╗
> ║    n ║  5n² + 3n ║       0.001n³ ║
> ╠══════╬═══════════╬═══════════════╣
> ║    1 ║         8 ║         0.001 ║
> ║    2 ║        26 ║         0.008 ║
> ║    3 ║        54 ║         0.027 ║
> ║    4 ║        92 ║         0.064 ║
> ║    5 ║       140 ║         0.125 ║
> ║    6 ║       198 ║         0.216 ║
> ║  ... ║       ... ║           ... ║
> ║ 5000 ║ 125015000 ║ 125000000.000 ║
> ║ 5001 ║ 125065008 ║ 125075015.001 ║
> ╚══════╩═══════════╩═══════════════╝
> ```

Temos o oposto do caso anterior, para quaisquer valores de [image: n >= 5001], o valor de [image: 5n²+3n] é menor. Isso significa que [image: 5n²+3n] tem seu valor ultrapassado por qualquer função cúbica (mesmo que o coeficiente utilizado seja muito pequeno), dado um valor de [image: n] suficientemente grande.

Como você já deve ter notado, os termos de menor grau e os coeficientes pouco importam no final. Se a classe [image: k] adequada tiver sido escolhida para qualquer função [image: f] tal que [image: f(n) in Theta(k(n))], então quaisquer coeficientes [image: a] e [image: b] adequados utilizados servirão e os termos de menor grau tornar-se-ão irrelevantes. Se a classe escolhida for inadequada, então não existirão termos [image: a] e [image: b] que satisfaçam a equação do [image: Theta] do começo dessa resposta.

Com isso, temos que todas as funções quadráticas estão na classe [image: Theta(n²)]. Todas as lineares estão na classe [image: Theta(n²)]. Todas as cúbicas estão na classe [image: Theta(n³)]. Todas as logarítmicas estão na classe [image: Theta(log n)]. Todas as exponenciais estão na classe [image: Theta(2^n)].

Em geral as classes seguem uma hierarquia semelhante a isso:

> [image: classes de complexidade mais comuns]

Essas são as classes de complexidade mais comuns.

## E quanto ao "assintótico"?

Por comportamento assintótico, entende-se o comportamento de uma função tendendo ao infinito. Ou seja, se considerarmos [image: n] com um valor bem grande. Como já demonstrado acima, quando isso ocorre, os termos de menor grau se tornam desprezíveis.

## E quanto ao O e ao Ω?

Vamos relembrar a equação do [image: Theta]:

> [image: equação]

Vamos focar nessa parte:

> [image: inequação]

Isso poderia ser dividido em duas inequações:

> [image: inequação]
>   [image: inequação]

E então teríamos isso:

> [image: equação]
>   [image: equação]

E como consequência:

> [image: equação]

A notação [image: O] (lê-se "ó grande") é bem popular, mais popular que o [image: Theta] inclusive. O [image: O] representa o limite superior de uma função, mas esse limite não precisa ser exato. Ou seja, trata-se de algo que a função nunca ultrapassa dado um valor de [image: n] suficientemente grande. Logo, se você tem alguma função [image: d] tal que [image: d in O(n²)], então dá para se dizer que [image: d] é quadrático **ou inferior**.

Já o [image: Omega] (lê-se "ômega grande") é o limite inferior (ou seja, algo que nunca é ultrapassado para baixo), que também não precisa ser exato. Logo, se você tem alguma função [image: d] tal que [image: d in Omega(n²)], então dá para se dizer que [image: d] é quadrático **ou superior**.

Quando o limite inferior e superior coincidem (mesmo que com coeficientes diferentes), então temos o [image: Theta]. Logo, se você tem alguma função [image: d] tal que [image: d in Theta(n²)], então dá para se dizer que [image: d] é quadrático, **nem mais e nem menos**. Dá para dizer também que [image: d in O(n²)] e [image: d in Omega(n²)] ao mesmo tempo.

Ou seja, se [image: s(n) = n²], temos que:

> [image: s in Omega(n)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in Theta(n)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in O(n)]
>   
>   [image: s in Omega(n²)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in Theta(n²)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in O(n²)]
>   
>   [image: s in Omega(n³)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in Theta(n³)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in O(n³)]

## E quanto ao o e ao ω?

Enquanto que o [image: O] indica um limite superior para a função, o [image: o] (lê-se "ó pequeno") representa o que está além desse limite. Da mesma forma, o [image: Omega] representa o limite inferior, ao passo que [image: omega] (lê-se "ômega pequeno") representa o que está aquém desse limite. Logo:

> [image: s in omega(n)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in o(n)]
>   
>   [image: s in omega(n²)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in o(n²)]
>   
>   [image: s in omega(n³)]
>    | 
>   [image: s in o(n³)]

Isso ocorre porque [image: s], que é quadrático, está além do linear, logo [image: s in omega(n)]. Porém está aquém do cúbico, e portanto [image: s in o(n³)].

## Notação com =

Frequentemente, você vê pessoas utilizando [image: h = Theta(n²)] ao invés de [image: h in Theta(n²)]. A rigor isso daí é um abuso da notação do "=", mas é um abuso comum e que todos fazem, inclusive em artigos acadêmicos muito conceituados. O certo seria usar o [image: in] uma vez que o [image: Theta(n²)] representa o conjunto de funções que são quadráticas e o que está sendo observado não é igualdade entre conjuntos e sim o pertencimento de uma função a um determinado conjunto de funções.