# Comparação de elementos de uma lista em JAVA

Tags: java, csv

Gostaria de que me dessem uma luz em relação a esse exercício. Preciso imprimir no console o nome e preço dos dois produtos mais caros lidos a partir de um arquivo `.csv` porém ele apenas está imprimindo o último nome e preço da planilha. Acho que o problema deve ser no for utilizado para a comparação. Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma comparação eficiente dos elementos da lista.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exercicio {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    File estoque = new File("C:\\estoque.csv");

    try{
        String fileLines = new String();

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(estoque);
        reader.nextLine();

        List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
        Produto produto = null;
        String[] linha;

        while(reader.hasNext()){

            fileLines = reader.nextLine();
            linha = fileLines.split(";");


            produto = new Produto();
            produto.nomeProduto = linha[0];
            produto.marca = linha[1];

            try{
            produto.preco = Double.parseDouble(linha[2]);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                produto.preco = 0;
            }
            try{
            produto.estoque = Integer.parseInt(linha[3]);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                produto.estoque = 0;
            }
            produtos.add(produto);
        }

        /*for(Produto p : produtos){
            System.out.println(); // IMPRIMIR INFORMAÇÕES


        }*/

            double maiorPreco = 0;
            double segundoMaiorPreco = 0;
            double segundoMaior = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < produtos.size()-1; i++){
               if(produto.preco > maiorPreco){
                   maiorPreco = produto.preco;
               }

           }
            System.out.println(maiorPreco);

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    }
    }
 }

class Produto {

public String nomeProduto;
public  String marca;
public double preco;
public int estoque;

}
```

Comment: Você não precisa de uma lista

Comment: como não? pode explicar?

Comment: Respondendo... segure as contas

Answer (score 1):

Temos algumas estratégias para se analisar aqui:

1. manter toda a lista e selecionar os 2 maiores
2. manter toda a lista e ordenar ela no final, selecionando os 2 maiores após a ordenação
3. manter apenas 2 elementos, os 2 maiores, atualizando-os a cada leitura
4. criar uma estrutura de dados tal que ela mantenha os `n` maiores elementos passados, com `n == 2`

Existem algumas alternativas que são, no mínimo, ingênuas. Eu diria que seria tolice usar elas:

5. manter toda a lista, remover o maior e elemento e separá-lo, então selecionar o maior elemento da lista restante
6. manter toda a lista, selecionar o maior elemento, em seguida selecionar o maior elemento que seja menor do que o elemento selecionado anteriormente

Particularmente eu iria para a alternativa 3. Mas vamos ver em ordem. Antes, gostaria de apresentar algumas funções auxiliares para ordenar o código.

## Funções auxiliares

A primeira que eu gostaria é separar o preenchimento de um `Produto` a partir de uma linha de leitura. Depois, gostaria de criar uma comparação entre dois objetos do classe `Produto`, retornando o resultado da comparação. Por fim, não custa nada ter uma função que transforme um produto em uma `String` pronta para ser impressa.

### Criação de um `Produto` a partir de uma linha

Aqui, a intenção é receber uma linha e transformar em `Produto`. Pode ser implementado de diversas formas. Vou sugerir aqui criar um `Supplier<Produto>`, até o momento em que ele gere nulo, que deve ser encarado como fim da leitura.

Para criar esse fornecedor de objetos, vou usar uma função para gerar isso. Também vou fazer uma função `Function<String,Produto>` para fazer o *parse* do CSV.

```
public Produto parseProdutoLinhaCsv(String linha) {
    String []colunas = fileLines.split(";");

    Produto produto = new Produto();
    produto.nomeProduto = colunas[0];
    produto.marca = colunas[1];

    try {
        produto.preco = Double.parseDouble(colunas[2]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        produto.preco = 0;
    }
    try {
        produto.estoque = Integer.parseInt(colunas[3]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        produto.estoque = 0;
    }

    return produto;
}

public Supplier<Produto> fornecedorProduto(Scanner scanArquivo) {
    return () -> {
        if (scanArquivo.hasNext()) {
            return parseProdutoLinhaCsv(scanArquivo.nextLine());
        }
        return null;
    };
}
```

Para fazer a leitura, vou usar a seguinte iteração:

```
[... linhas anteriores ...]
Scanner scanArquivo = new Scanner(estoque);
for (Supplier<Produto> fornecedorProduto, Produto prod = fornecedorProduto.get(); prod != null; prod = fornecedorProduto.get()) {
    // ... faz coisas enquanto lê
}
[... fim da leitura ...]
```

### Comparando dois `Produto`s

Aqui, a comparação se dá através do seu campo `preco`. Vou fazer uma função sinal para poder ser usada para ordenação, e também uma função booleana para simplesmente saber se `p1` é mais caro do que `p2`:

```
public int cmpProduto(Produto p1, Produto p2) {
    return p1.preco < p2.preco? -1: p1.preco > p2.preco? +1: 0;
}

public boolean maisCaro(Produto p1, Produto p2) {
    return p1.preco > p2.preco;
}
```

### `String` de apresentação

Neste caso, vou ter um "apresentador" que vai consumir um `Produto` e gerar uma saída na `stdout`/`sysout`. Para tal, vou criar uma função separada só para transformar de `Produto` para `String`, então se eu quiser, por exemplo, imprimir em um arquivo, é só usar esse função `Produto |-> String`

```
public String produto2string(Produto p) {
    return p != null? "" + p.nomeProduto + ": $" + p.preco: "sem produto";
}

public Consumer<Produto> apresentadorProduto(Function<Produto,String> transformaProduto, Consumer<String> apresentador) {
    return (p) -> apresentador.accept(transformaProduto(p));
}
```

Para criar o apresentador desejado:

```
[... linhas anteriores ...]
Consumer<Produto> apresentador = apresentadorProduto(this::produto2string, System.out::println);
[... linhas posteriores, que alguma deve usar o apresentador ...]
```

## Diversas soluções

### Manter toda a lista e selecionar os 2 maiores

> Tempo de execução: `o(k)`
>
> Memória usada máxima: `o(k)`

Esta foi a estratégia que você tentou usar. Vou apontar quais os pontos de problemas.

A leitura em si você fez já. Vou alterar aqui ligeiramente para seguir o exemplo. Mas a iteração em si está errada. Começando pelo fato de que ela não percorre todos os elementos. O último elemento, de índice `produtos.size() - 1`, não está sendo considerado.

Você vai precisar de três variáveis distintas para cá:

- a variável de iteração
- a variável indicando quem é o maior produto
- a variável indicando quem é o segundo maior produto

Podemos começar, podemos considerar que os dois primeiros elementos da lista são os nossos primeiros candidatos a maior e segundo maior. Então, precisamos garantir quem é o maior e, em seguida, manter o segundo maior na posição adequada. Depois disso, é só atualizar essas variáveis com os valores relevantes conforme são lidos os demais valores.

```
[... linhas anteriores ...]

List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanArquivo = new Scanner(estoque);
for (Supplier<Produto> fornecedorProduto = fornecedorProduto(scanArquivo), Produto prod = fornecedorProduto.get(); prod != null; prod = fornecedorProduto.get()) {
    produtos.add(prod);
}

Produto maisCaro;
Produto segundoMaisCaro;

if (produtos.size() == 0) {
    maisCaro = null;
    segundoMaisCaro = null;
} else if (produtos.size() == 1) {
    maisCaro = produtos.get(0);
    segundoMaisCaro = null;
} else {
    Produto candidato;

    maisCaro = produtos.get(0);
    candidato = produtos.get(1);

    if (maisCaro(candidato, maisCaro)) {
        // o candidato é mais caro do que o primeiro elemento
        // precisa "bolhar" o antigo primeiro elemento para "baixo"
        segundoMaisCaro = maisCaro;
        maisCaro = candidato;
    } else {
        // o candidato deve ocupar a segunda posição
        segundoMaisCaro = candidato;
    }

    // lista já começa ignorando os dois primeiros elementos
    for (int i = 2; i < produtos.size(); i++) {
        candidato = produtos.get(i);
        if (maisCaro(candidato, maisCaro)) {
            // o candidato é mais caro do que o primeiro elemento
            // precisa "bolhar" o antigo primeiro elemento para "baixo"
            segundoMaisCaro = maisCaro;
            maisCaro = candidato;
        } else if (maisCaro(candidato, segundoMaisCaro)) {
            // o candidato é o mais caro do que o segundo elemento, substitui ele
            segundoMaisCaro = candidato;
        }
    }
}

// ao sair daqui, eu tenho preenchido os dois mais caros (ou nulo, caso tenha menos elementos)

Consumer<Produto> apresentador = apresentadorProduto(this::produto2string, System.out::println);
apresentador.accept(maisCaro);
apresentador.accept(segundoMaisCaro);

[... linhas posteriores ...]
```

### Manter toda a lista e ordenar ela no final, selecionando os 2 maiores após a ordenação

> Tempo de execução: `o(k log(k))`
>
> Memória usada máxima: `o(k)`

Aqui a ideia é ordenar a lista e pegar apenas os primeiros elementos (os mais caros). O padrão da ordem natural é ordenar de modo ascendente, mas isso botaria os preços maiores pro final. Para evitar isso, vou pegar o ["comparador reverso"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--).

Note que o tempo de execução total está maior do que o anterior, porque agora estamos usando um algoritmo de ordenação comparativo ([`List.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) usa [TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)). A memória usada pelo `TimSort` é `o(k)`, portanto mantendo a [complexidade assintótica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236960/64969) espacial constante.

```
[... linhas anteriores ...]

List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanArquivo = new Scanner(estoque);
for (Supplier<Produto> fornecedorProduto = fornecedorProduto(scanArquivo), Produto prod = fornecedorProduto.get(); prod != null; prod = fornecedorProduto.get()) {
    produtos.add(prod);
}


Comparator<Produto> cmpNatural = this::cmpProduto;
produtos.sort(cmpNatural.reversed());

Produto maisCaro;
Produto segundoMaisCaro;

if (produtos.size() == 0) {
    maisCaro = segundoMaisCaro = null;
} else if (produtos.size() == 1) {
    maisCaro = produtos.get(0);
    segundoMaisCaro = null;
} else {
    maisCaro = produtos.get(0);
    segundoMaisCaro = produtos.get(1);
}

Consumer<Produto> apresentador = apresentadorProduto(this::produto2string, System.out::println);
apresentador.accept(maisCaro);
apresentador.accept(segundoMaisCaro);

[... linhas posteriores ...]
```

### Manter apenas 2 elementos, os 2 maiores, atualizando-os a cada leitura

> Tempo de execução: `o(k)`
>
> Memória usada máxima: `o(1)`

Aqui, a ideia é particularmente distinta das anteriores. Não se deve manter mais do que 3 variáveis do tipo `Produto`:

- a mais cara de todas
- a segunda mais cara
- uma nova que é candidata a entrar

A ideia é fazer de tal sorte que eu controle isso logo na entrada. Como consequência imediata, não é necessário manter todos os objetos criados em um vetor, logo a memória de trabalho de fato usada é constante (obviamente que a criação de objetos vai fazer com que alguns deles permaneçam inalcançáveis na memória até o GC rodar e limpá-los):

```
List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanArquivo = new Scanner(estoque);
Supplier<Produto> fornecedorProduto = fornecedorProduto(scanArquivo);

Produto maisCaro = fornecedorProduto.get();
Produto segundoMaisCaro = fornecedorProduto.get();

// mantendo os dois primeiros ordenados
if (segundoMaisCaro != null && maisCaro(segundoMaisCaro, maisCaro)) {
    Produto swap = maisCaro;
    maisCaro = segundoMaisCaro;
    segundoMaisCaro = maisCaro;
}

for (Produto prod = fornecedorProduto.get(); prod != null; prod = fornecedorProduto.get()) {
    if (maisCaro(prod, maisCaro)) {
        // precisa "bolhar" o antigo primeiro elemento para "baixo"
        segundoMaisCaro = maisCaro;
        maisCaro = prod;
    } else if (maisCaro(prod, segundoMaisCaro)) {
        // preciso só trocar o último produto
        segundoMaisCaro = prod;
    }
}

Consumer<Produto> apresentador = apresentadorProduto(this::produto2string, System.out::println);
apresentador.accept(maisCaro);
apresentador.accept(segundoMaisCaro);

[... linhas posteriores ...]
```

> Depois eu continuo as outras 3 opções

Answer (score 1):

Aqui eu não vou optimizar o código(a outra resposta já apresentou um monte de soluções boas), em vez disso vou apenas indicar o erro que faz o programa imprimir apenas o maior preço.

## Versão longa

O problema está aqui:

```
for(int i = 0; i < produtos.size()-1; i++){
       if(produto.preco > maiorPreco){
            maiorPreco = produto.preco;
       }
}
```

Não há nenhuma operação que pega o item de índice `i` da lista `produtos` e armazena em `produto`. Por consequência, o objeto guardado em `produto` é o ultimo produto lido no laço anterior.

Para resolver o problema, coloque a seguinte operação antes da comparação:

```
produto = produtos.get(i);
```

O código final deve ficar assim:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Exercicio {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    File estoque = new File("C:\\estoque.csv");

    try{
        String fileLines = new String();

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(estoque);
        reader.nextLine();

        List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<Produto>();
        Produto produto = null;
        String[] linha;

        while(reader.hasNext()){

            fileLines = reader.nextLine();
            linha = fileLines.split(";");


            produto = new Produto();
            produto.nomeProduto = linha[0];
            produto.marca = linha[1];

            try{
            produto.preco = Double.parseDouble(linha[2]);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                produto.preco = 0;
            }
            try{
            produto.estoque = Integer.parseInt(linha[3]);
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                produto.estoque = 0;
            }
            produtos.add(produto);
        }

        /*for(Produto p : produtos){
            System.out.println(); // IMPRIMIR INFORMAÇÕES


        }*/

            double maiorPreco = 0;
            double segundoMaiorPreco = 0;
            double segundoMaior = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < produtos.size()-1; i++){
               produto = produtos.get(i); //Isto altera o produto sendo comparado.
               if(produto.preco > maiorPreco){
                   maiorPreco = produto.preco;
               }

           }
            System.out.println(maiorPreco);

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    }
    }
 }

class Produto {

public String nomeProduto;
public  String marca;
public double preco;
public int estoque;

}
```

Caso queira também guardar o segundo elemento mais caro, altere o segundo laço para isso:

```
for(int i = 0; i < produtos.size()-1; i++){
   produto = produtos.get(i);
   if(produto.preco > maiorPreco){
      segundoMaiorPreco = maiorPreco;
      maiorPreco = produto.preco;
   }
}
System.out.println(maiorPreco); //Maior preço
System.out.println(segundoMaiorPreco); //Segundo maior preço
```

Caso queira optimizar o código, a resposta anterior já apresentou um conjunto bom de opções.

## Versão TL;DR

Você esqueceu de atualizar a variável `produto` no ultimo `for`.