# Como um Merge sort funciona exatamente?

Tags: c, merge

Eu já sei que ele usa recursão e que ordena os vetores até ficarem ordenados, porém, é exatamente nessa parte que gera minhas dúvidas. Como eu sei até quando ele vai chamar o método Merge? Quando ele vai sair do primeiro merge e entrar no segundo? Qual o motivo de o merge ficar só dividindo numero do vetor inicial com o final? Quando que o while vai ser chamado?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mergeSort( int *vetorDesorndeado, int posicaoInicio, int posicaoFim ) 
{
   int i,j,k,metadeTamanho,*vetorTemp;

   if ( posicaoInicio == posicaoFim ) return;

   // ordenacao recursiva das duas metades

   metadeTamanho = ( posicaoInicio+posicaoFim )/2;



   mergeSort( vetorDesorndeado, posicaoInicio, metadeTamanho);

   mergeSort( vetorDesorndeado, metadeTamanho+1,posicaoFim );


   // intercalacao no vetor temporario t
   i = posicaoInicio;
   j = metadeTamanho+1;
   k = 0;
   vetorTemp = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (posicaoFim-posicaoInicio+1));


   printf( " VALOR DE I : %d , VALOR DE J : %d , VALOR DE K : %d, VALOR DE FIM : %d  \n ", i, j, k, posicaoFim);
   while( i < metadeTamanho+1 || j  < posicaoFim+1 )

   { 
      if ( i == metadeTamanho+1 )
      { // i passou do final da primeira metade, pegar v[j]

         vetorTemp[k] = vetorDesorndeado[j];
         j++;
         k++;
      } 
      else
      {
         if (j==posicaoFim+1) 
         { 

            // j passou do final da segunda metade, pegar v[i]
            vetorTemp[k] = vetorDesorndeado[i];
            i++;
            k++;
         } 
         else 
         {
            if (vetorDesorndeado[i] < vetorDesorndeado[j]) 
            { 

               vetorTemp[k] = vetorDesorndeado[i];
               i++;
               k++;
            } 
            else
            { 

              vetorTemp[k] = vetorDesorndeado[j];
              j++;
              k++;
            }
         }
      }

   }




    printf("\n");

   // copia vetor intercalado para o vetor original
   for( i = posicaoInicio; i <= posicaoFim; i++ )
   {
      vetorDesorndeado[i] = vetorTemp[i-posicaoInicio];
   }



   free(vetorTemp);
}

int main(){

    int tamanho;

    printf(" Qual o tamanho do vetor : ");
    scanf("%d",&tamanho);

    int vetor[tamanho];

    for(int i = 0; i <= tamanho-1; i++){

        printf(" Digite o %d numero ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vetor[i]);

        }

        mergeSort(vetor,0,tamanho-1);

        for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
           printf(" %d ", vetor[i]);    
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Já procurou em outras perguntas aqui do SOpt? Tenho certeza que eu mesmo já mencionei como funciona em uma questão de complexidade computacional, talvez tenha alguma pergunta direta sobre isso

Comment: Aqui eu menciono o seu funcionamento: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237026/64969 ; pegar duas listas ordenadas e "criar" uma terceira lista ordenada