# Como provar a complexidade de um algoritmo?

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Eu tenho algumas questões sobre analisar complexidade de algoritmo, eu tenho a resposta correta delas(verdadeiro ou falsa),porém não sei como provar, se alguém conseguir me explicar o raciocínio pra chegar a prova real delas:

1. 100n não está em Ω(n²) -> Gabarito diz que é verdadeiro.
2. n + log n está em Θ(n) -> Gabarito diz que é verdadeiro
3. Podemos dizer que uma um algoritmo com complexidade f(n)  está em O(f(n/2)). -> Gabarito diz que é falso.
4. Uma função f(n) domina assintoticamente outra função g(n) se existem duas constantes positivas c e n_0 tais que, para n≥n_0, temos  f(n)≤c∙g(n).Gabarito diz falso.
5. Para duas funções g(n) e f(n) temos que f(n)=Ω(g(n)) se somente se f(n)=O(g(n)).gabarito diz que é falsa.

Comment: Nas threads relacionadas, encontrei essa aqui que também é relevante para a sua pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236960/como-provar-a-ordem-assint%c3%b3tica-de-um-algoritmo?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Em análise assintótica, quem domina é o termo com maior magnitude. Por exemplo, na expressão:

N³ + 1000N² + 10000N + 1000000, quem domina é O N³. Isso pq conforme N vai ao infinito, o valor dos demais termos torna-se irrisório perto de N³.

Então, avaliando as proposições.

- 1: 100N não está em O(N²): Verdadeiro. 100N está em O(N), pq o expoente do maior termo é 1.
- 2: N + logN está em O(N): Verdadeiro. N cresce muito mais rápido do que logN e portanto domina a expressão.
- 5: `f(n) = Ω(g(n))` se e somente se `f(n) = O(g(n)) => Ω(g(n)) = O(g(n))`. O que essa expressão está nos dizendo é que para uma função ser igual ao melhor caso de outra função, também deve ser igual ao pior caso, o que é um absurdo. Basta tomar uma função qualquer que tenha melhor caso diferente do pior caso, que irá contradizer essa proposição, provando sua falsidade.

Na terceira me parece que o gabarito está errado, e a quarta não sei responder. Peço que consulte seu professor e me retorne, também quero saber.

Espero ter ajudado ;)

Comment: Cara, obrigado pela resposta, vou verificar com professor. Você simplesmente plotou o gráfico num wolfram da vida e analisou o crescimento?

Comment: Não entendi ainda sua explicação sobre N+ log n, pois você justifica analisando o big O, sendo que a questão é sobre Θ.

Comment: Então, não é necessário plotar, você faz no olho mesmo - só olhar pro termo de maior potência. Um exercício que você pode fazer é plotar duas funções no Wolfram, uma com o maior termo e outra com os demais termos, e você vai ver que a primeira vai crescer exponencialmente mais rápido do que a segunda.

Comment: A questão do caso médio foi desatenção minha mesmo, acredito que você consiga resolver pela mesma linha de pensamento, mas não tenho certeza.