# como faço para não imprimir números repetidos?

Tags: c, array

Como faço para não imprimir os números repetidos ? vi alguns exemplos na internet mas eram algo bem complexo no qual não entendi nada :x

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
int vetA[10], vetB[10], vetC[20], i, j;

printf ("Informe 10 valores para o VETOR A:\n\n");
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
scanf ("%d", &vetA[i]);

printf ("\nInforme 10 valores para o VETOR B:\n\n");
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
scanf ("%d", &vetB[i]);

    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    vetC[i] = vetA[i];

    for (i=5; i<10; i++)
    vetC[i] = vetB[i-5];

    printf ("\nA uniao dos vetores e:\n\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf ("%d, ", vetC[i]);
}
```

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236929/64969

Comment: "não imprimir numeros repetidos" - penso que o que quer dizer é construir um vetor resultante sem números repetidos certo ?

Comment: @Isac quero que o vetorC nao imprima 2x o mesmo numero tipo eu digito o numero 1 no vetorA e B mas so vai imprimir o numero 1 apenas uma vez nao vai repetir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode resolver o problema, adicionado apenas ao `vetC` sempre que sabe que o elemento ainda não existe em `vetC`. Para simplificar podemos começar por construir uma função que faça a verificação:

```
int existe(int* vetor, int tamanho, int elemento){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; ++i){
        if (vetor[i] == elemento) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Repare em 2 pormenores importantes desta função:

- O tipo de retorno foi marcado com `int` quando este é utilizado como `1` ou `0`, de verdadeiro ou falso. Isto acontece porque em C não temos nativamente booleanos.
- O tamanho do vetor teve de ser passado como parâmetro pois não há forma de o saber dentro da função.

Agora no `main` percorre-se os dois vetores `vetA` e `vetB` e apenas se adiciona se não existirem já:

```
int tamC = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    //se vetA[i] ainda não existe em vetC adiciona a vetC e aumenta a quantidade
    if (!existe(vetC, tamC, vetA[i])) vetC[tamC++] = vetA[i];
    if (!existe(vetC, tamC, vetB[i])) vetC[tamC++] = vetB[i];
}
```

Repare que apenas se não existir é adicionado no `vetC` e incrementada a variável `tamC`. Isto significa que no fim do `for`, `tamC` indica o tamanho real de `vetC` tendo em conta os elementos duplicados que não foram inseridos.

Esta solução adiciona elementos de A e B intercaladamente. Se pretender manter a ordem original, com todos os de A e depois todos os de B, tem que separar em 2 `for`:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    if (!existe(vetC, tamC, vetA[i])) vetC[tamC++] = vetA[i];

for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    if (!existe(vetC, tamC, vetB[i])) vetC[tamC++] = vetB[i];
```

Se o tamanho dos vetores é uma constante definida inicialmente então é melhor tornar isso explicito com um `#define` por exemplo:

```
#define TAMANHO 5
```

[Veja o programa com estas alterações no Ideone](https://ideone.com/orSfeo)

Nota final: Esta solução é quadrática (O(n²)) e por isso poderá não servir se a entrada de dados for gigantesca. Nessa caso poderá optar por outra solução mais eficiente, ainda que implique pré processamento dos dados de entrada.

Comment: Para os curiosos, o jeito mais eficiente é ordenar os dois conjuntos e fazer a união deles. Tendo dois conjuntos ordenados, o tempo para se concatenar os elementos únicos é `o(|a| + |b|)`. A ordenação genérica dos dois conjuntos `a` e `b` pode custar até `o(a log a + b log b)`