# Como eliminar números repetidos de um vetor visualg?

Tags: portugol, pascal, visualg

```
algoritmo "semnome"
// Função :
// Autor :
// Data : 06/02/2018
// Seção de Declarações
var
veto1 : vetor[0..9] de inteiro
veto2 : vetor[0..9] de inteiro
j,i : inteiro
inicio
para i de 0 ate 9 faca
   leia(veto1[i])
fimpara
para i de 0 ate 9 faca
para j de 0 ate 9 faca
     se(veto1[i] <> veto1[j])entao
      veto2[i] <- veto1[i]
     fimse
fimpara
fimpara
para i de 0 ate 9 faca
   escreva(veto2[i])
fimpara
fimalgoritmo
```

Quero pegar 10 números e armazenar em um vetor o vetor 1 isso já conseguiu quero agora pegar os valores e colocar todos no vetor 2 porem excluindo a repetição exemplo
1.2.3.4.4.5.6.7.8.9
aparece só 
123456789

Comment: Everton, ideal é sempre você colocar o código fonte, ao invés de imagens (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Alterar agora, desculpe

Comment: @rLinhares já modifiquei você poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Discorro sobre esse assunto nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236929/64969

Comment: Também vale a pena ler aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236518/64969

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser realizado da seguinte maneira

```
para i de 0 ate 9 faca
   para j de 0 ate 9 faca
      se ((x = 1) e  (veto1[i] = veto2[j]))entao
         veto2[i]  <- 0
      fimse
      se ((x = 0) e (veto1[i] = veto2[j]))entao
         x <- 1
      fimse
   fimpara
   x <- 0
fimpara
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma seria verificar para cada elemento do veto1 se ele já existe no veto2, caso não exista, adiciona ele ao veto2.

Poderia utilizar o conceito de *flag* para indicar se já existe ou não no veto2.

Algo assim:

```
algoritmo "Apenas números não repetidos"
// Autor : Simon Viegas
// Data  : 03/08/2021
var
   veto1 : vetor[0..9] de inteiro
   veto2 : vetor[0..9] de inteiro
   i, j, cont : inteiro
   invalido : logico
inicio
   //preenche o veto1
   ALEATORIO 1,9
   para i de 0 ate 9 faca
      leia(veto1[i])
   fimPara
   ALEATORIO OFF

   //preenche o veto2
   para i de 0 ate 9 faca
      invalido <- FALSO //inicializa como inválido (repetido)

      para j de 0 ate cont faca //para cada posição do veto2
         se (veto1[i] = veto2[j]) entao //verifica se o valor já existe
            invalido <- VERDADEIRO //marca como inválido
         fimSe
      fimPara
       
      se (NAO invalido) entao //se não é inválido
         veto2[cont] <- veto1[i] //armazena no vetor 2
         cont <- cont+1 //atualiza o contador de itens no veto2
      fimSe
   fimPara

   //exibe os valores de veto2 na tela
   para i de 0 ate cont-1 faca
      escreva(veto2[i])
   fimPara
fimAlgoritmo
```

Exemplo de tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]