# Filtrar elementos comuns em dois Arranjos

Tags: java

Como eu faço para conseguir um terceiro arranjo com a intersecção (elementos comuns entre os dois arranjos) entre dois arranjos sem repetição?

```
int [] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};    // arranjo 1
int [] b = {0,1,2,3};          // arranjo 2

int [] c = {1,2,3};            // arranjo de intersecção
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No caso, você desejar "*elementos comuns*" descarta-me a possibilidade de se pensar em arranjo. Pelo conceito que estou acostumado de *arranjo* a ordem importa. Numa interseção, a ordem é totalmente irrelevante.

Por exemplo, os arranjos `{0,1}` e `{1,0}` são diferentes. Se forem tratados como *conjuntos*, entretanto, eles são os mesmos conjuntos. Não conheço qual seria a definição formal de interseção para arranjos, porém para conjuntos é assim:

[image: o elemento só está na interseção se estiver em ambos os conjuntos]

Se você não tem limitação alguma com o Java que está usando, pode usar o `Set` diretamente e resolver o seu problema. Algo mais ou menos assim (versão Java 8):

```
int []a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int []b = {0, 1, 2, 3};

// cria um objeto da classe Set sobre o array a
Set<Integer> setA = IntStream.of(a).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
// cria um objeto da classe Set sobre o array b
Set<Integer> setB = IntStream.of(b).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

// determina a interseção: verifica se os elementos de a estão em b, transformando em array logo em seguida
int []c = setA.stream().filter(b::contains).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

---

Agora, isso me parece um exercício proposto por um professor de modo que você desenvolva toda a lógica por traz disso, usando-se do mínimo de implementações externas do assunto. Então, posso assumir que é tudo contigo? Isto é, todo código sendo executado provém d seu teclado?

Pois bem, o primeiro passo seria dar um jeito de sobreviver à limitação do tamanho do conjunto. Eu proponho uma solução porca, nojenta e engenhosa: criamos um vetor rascunho do tamanho máximo possível e operamos em cima dele. Então, dado que contamos todos os elementos da interseção, criamos um vetor de tamanho adequado e jogamos do rascunho para o novo array a parte interessante:

```
int []a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int []b = {0, 1, 2, 3};

int []rascunho = new int[a.length < b.length? a.length: b.length];
int tamanhoIntersecoesNoRascunho = 0;

// iterando sobre os elementos no vetor a
for (int elA: a) {
  // primeiro, devo verificar se já foi inserido no rascunho para não repetir...
  boolean contidoRascunho = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoIntersecoesNoRascunho; i++) {
    // sim, já fora inserido no rascunho
    if (elA == rascunho[i]) {
      contidoRascunho  = true;
      break;
    }

    // se já está no rascunho, vá para o próximo elemento a ser processado
    if (contidoRascunho) {
      continue;
    }

    // verifica se pertence ao outro conjunto
    for (int elB: b) {
      // foi detectada a interseção
      if (elA == elB) {
        rascunho[tamanhoIntersecoesNoRascunho] = elA;
        tamanhoIntersecoesNoRascunho++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

// criando o vetor final, de tamanho adequado
inc []c = new int[tamanhoIntersecoesNoRascunho];
for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoIntersecoesNoRascunho; i++) {
  c[i] = rascunho[i];
}
```

Essa solução simplesmente funciona, mas ela (em sua atual encarnação) é ruim por diversos motivos:

- seu tempo de execução é de `o(n * m)`, sendo `n` o tamanho do primeiro conjunto e `m` o tamanho do segundo conjunto; creio que piore um pouco mais se tiver uma grande interseção, porém isso não mudaria a [complexidade assintótica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236960/64969)
- exige um gasto de memória extra, mesmo sendo plausível que esse espaço no final acabe nem sendo utilizado

Você até consegue melhorar a parte do tempo de execução usando a lógica de, inicialmente, pré-processar os vetores para deixá-los em ordem crescente. Nesse caso, porém, note que a iteração deve ser distinta. Leia mais [[1]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236929/64969) [[2]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236518/64969). Abstraindo a parte da ordenação, ficaria assim a detecção:

```
int []a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int []b = {0, 1, 2, 3};

// ... rotina misteriosa que ordena a e b ...

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int idxRascunho = 0;

int []rascunho = new int[a.length < b.length? a.length: b.length];
int ultimoElementoAdicionado = 0;

while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
  if (a[i] == b[j]) {
    int candidato = a[i];

    if (idxRascunho == 0 || ultimoElementoAdicionado != candidato) {
      rascunho[idxRascunho] = candidato;
      idxRascunho++;
    }

    i++;
    j++;
  }  else if (a[i] < b[j]) {
    i++;
  } else { // a[i] > b[j]...
    j++;
  }
}

// criando o vetor final, de tamanho adequado
inc []c = new int[idxRascunho];
for (int i = 0; i < idxRascunho; i++) {
  c[i] = rascunho[i];
}
```

Essa solução melhora a parte do desempenho, porém continua com problema de memória...

Para resolver isso, que tal uma lista ligada? Então, assumindo que o código é totalmente nosso, podemos fazer uma lista ligada. No caso, nossa lista será extremamente simples e cada nó conterá apenas 3 informações:

1. o número que ele carrega consigo
2. o ponteiro para o próximo elemento da lista (`null` significa fim da lista)
3. o tamanho da lista até então, contando o nó atual

Podemos adicionar um método utilitário nela que transforma a lista em um vetor de inteiros.

Assim, nossa classe de nó de lista ligada pode ser definida assim:

```
class Nodo {
  final Nodo proximo;
  final int tamanho;
  final int conteudo;

  // para construir um novo nó, só preciso ser informado de seu conteúdo e do vizinho
  Nodo(int conteudo, Nodo proximo) {
    this.conteudo = conteudo;
    this.proximo = proximo;
    this.tamanho = (proximo != null? proximo.tamanho: 0) + 1;
  }

  static int[] toArray(Nodo nodo) {
    if (nodo == null) {
      return new int[0];
    }
    int []vetor = new int[nodo.tamanho];
    for (Nodo it = nodo; it != null; it = it.proximo) {
      // como armazenamos em cada nó o tamanho do lista que se segue + 1,
      // então se pusermos o seu conteúdo na posição it.tamanho-1 manteremos
      // a ordem de inserção dos nodos dentro do vetor, então o vetor
      // gerado estará ordenada
      vetor[it.tamanho - 1] = it.conteudo;
    }
    return vetor;
  }
}
```

Como a lista ligada contém, necessariamente, o maior elemento descoberto na interseção, então podemos criar a seguinte função utilitária para saber se, por acaso, o elemento já foi inserido na interseção:

```
private static boolean candidatoEhNovidade(int candidato, Nodo ultimoNodo) {
  // se está nulo é porque não tem elementos na interseção
  if (ultimoNodo == null) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return candidato != ultimoNodo.conteudo;
  }
}
```

Então, em cima disso, podemos dar uma abstração em um método que faz a manutenção da lista, retornando a nova cabeça da lista:

```
private static Nodo insereSeNovidade(int candidato, Nodo ultimoNodo) {
  if (candidatoEhNovidade(candidato, ultimoNodo)) {
    return new Nodo(candidato, ultimoNodo);
  } else {
    // nada a fazer, então a lista continua no mesmo estado
    return ultimoNodo;
  }
}
```

E o miolo do programa seria isso:

```
int []a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
int []b = {0, 1, 2, 3};

// ... rotina misteriosa que ordena a e b ...

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
Nodo cabecaLista = null;

while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
  if (a[i] == b[j]) {
    cabecaLista = insereSeNovidade(a[i], cabecaLista);

    i++;
    j++;
  }  else if (a[i] < b[j]) {
    i++;
  } else { // a[i] > b[j]...
    j++;
  }
}

// criando o vetor final, de tamanho adequado
inc []c = Nodo.toArray(cabecaLista);
```

Assim, sem fazer uso de nada da biblioteca padrão do Java (exceto, talvez, na lacuna referente à ordenação), conseguimos criar a lista em tempo `o(n log n)` e com uso de memória assintoticamente igual ao tamanho da interseção entre os dois conjuntos.

Answer (score 4):

Devido a limitação do array necessitar ser iniciado já com seu tamanho, porém não é possivel identificar a quantidade de elementos em comum dos dois arrays iniciais, acredito que a solução abaixo pode ser válida:

```
int [] a = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};    // arranjo 1
int [] b = {0,1,2,3};          // arranjo 2
String intersec = "";

for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < b.length; y++){
        if(a[i] == b[y])
            intersec += a[i] + ";";
    }
}

String[] intersecao = intersec.split(";");

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(intersecao));
```

Veja funcionando no ideone: https://ideone.com/VuLuBJ

Caso precise do array resultante com inteiro, Pode seguir a dica [desta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164167/5524514) que, utilizando streams do java-8, converte o array de strings para int:

```
int[] arrayInt = Arrays.stream(intersecao).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```