# Identificar indices repetidos e efetuar a troca somente de um deles

Tags: array, python-2.7

Possuo o seguinte vetor:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3]
```

Preciso percorrer esse vetor e identificar quais os valores repetidos.

Após identificá-los, preciso que apenas um deles seja trocado por um valor aleatório entre 1 e 11.

Por exemplo:

O vetor de saída seria algo assim:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 9]
```

Ou seja, identifiquei que o índices 0 e 2 estão repetidos. Porém, efetuo a troca somente dos índices 4 e 5 e mantenho os valores do 0 e 2.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

Grato aos que puderem.

Comment: Apenas um deles ou ambos?

Comment: apenas um deles.

Comment: É importante manter a ordem?

Comment: Sim é preciso manter!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado se não for possível manter a ordem, não tem problema!

Comment: Dá para fazer mantendo a ordem, mas tornar o conjunto ordenado permite algumas abordagens mais preguiçosas e rápidas. Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/236518/64969), onde elaboro sobre identificação de elementos repetidos em um conjunto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma simples é percorrer todos os valores em `a`, verificar se o valor corrente pertence à lista `b`, que será a saída, e enquanto pertencer, sortear um novo número entre 1 e 11, até que este não esteja presente na lista para então adicioná-lo. Em Python, ficaria assim:

```
from random import randint

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3]
b = []

for value in a:
    while value in b:
        value = randint(1, 11)
    b.append(value)

print b
```

O resultado seria:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9]
```

Isto é, os índices 4 e 5 foram identificados como duplicados e foram sorteados outros valores, nesse casso 8 e 9 respectivamente.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/TMV8Yv).

Inclusive, esta lógica funcionará bem com mais de um valor repetido. Veja:

```
from random import randint

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b = []

for value in a:
    while value in b:
        value = randint(1, 11)
    b.append(value)

print b
```

Gerando o resultado:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 8, 6, 10]
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/LF1F3o).

Porém, se a lista de valores possuir mais de 11 elementos, chegará uma hora que o programa irá tentar sortear um valor e nunca encontrará um válido, pois todos os valores entre 1 e 11 pertencem à lista, ficando preso infinitamente no laço `while` - partindo da premissa que a lista de valores conterá inicialmente apenas valores entre 1 e 11. Desta forma, uma verificação quanto ao comprimento da lista deverá ser feita para evitar tal problema:

```
from random import randint

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
b = []

if len(a) <= 11:
    for value in a:
        while value in b:
            value = randint(1, 11)
        b.append(value)

    print b
else:
    print "A lista 'a' deve conter no máximo 11 elementos."
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/SNohe2).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funciona perfeitamente para o que eu preciso.