# SQLQuery - Alguns Registros duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Galera, na consulta abaixo está trazendo da seguinte forma.

> ```
> UsuID    Consultor   Tentativa 1 Abertos
> 95093    Gabriela         96
> ```

Porém, é era para trazer da seguinte forma:

> ```
> UsuID    Consultor   Tentativa 2 Abertos
> 95093    Gabriela         48
> ```

OBS: Quando eu executo uma das subconsultas por fora, os valores trazem normalmente, porém, quando eu junto com inner join, alguns valores são duplicados conforme exemplo acima.

```
select
s7.UsuID,s7.Consultor,SUM(s7.[Tentativa 1 Abertos]) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
from
(select U.UsuNome Consultor, U.UsuID, (COUNT((S.SolID))) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
    from Solicitacao S 
    left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
    and S.SolEstagioID IN (235,276,278,294) AND S.SolStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
    GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome

    union

    select U.UsuNome Consultor, U.UsuID, (COUNT((S.TarID))) AS [Tentativa 1 Abertos]
    from Tarefa S 
    left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
    and S.TarEstagioID IN (235,276,278,294) AND S.TarStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
    GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome) s7


inner join

(select U.UsuNome Consultor, U.UsuID, (COUNT((S.SolID))) AS [Tentativa 2 Abertos]
    from Solicitacao S 
    left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
    and S.SolEstagioID IN (236,277,279,295) AND S.SolStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
    GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome

    union all

    select U.UsuNome Consultor, U.UsuID, (COUNT((S.TarID))) AS [Tentativa 2 Abertos]
    from Tarefa S 
    left join Usuario U on U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
    WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'A' AND U.UsuIDGrupo = 30 AND U.EmpLiberada = 1 and u.UsuUsuario is not null
    and S.TarEstagioID IN (236,277,279,295) AND S.TarStatus IN (0,1,5)-- AND S.UsuIDCliente not in (select Y.UsuIDCliente from Solicitacao Y where Y.SolTipID in (710) and Y.SolStatus in (0,1,5))
    GROUP BY U.UsuID, U.UsuNome)s8

on s7.UsuID = s8.UsuID and s7.Consultor = s8.Consultor
group by s7.UsuID,s7.Consultor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que essa duplicação esteja na segunda consulta, onde você utiliza o [*union all*](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-utilizando-o-operador-union-e-union-all/37457).

Da uma lida [**nessa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153498/64073) mas de forma resumida, o *union all* considera pra consulta os itens duplicados. Acredito que seja esse o ponto.

Sendo (apenas) isso, utiliza nas duas consultas internas o ***union***, assim cada item será contabilizado apenas uma vez.

Comment: ôpa @rLinhares, eu já tinha testado dessa maneira utilizando só o union , porém, nao deu certo.

Comment: @RenanBessa, você precisaria trazer duas ocorrências? uma com "Tentativa 1 Abertos" e outra com "Tentativa 2 Abertos"??

Comment: isso mesmo trazendo exatamente na mesma coluna como exemplifiquei.