# Registros Aleatórios com Critérios

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Gostaria de algum comando em SQL para um banco de dados em MS-Access onde tenho **500 registros** e que retorne apenas **20 registros** de forma ***aleatória*** sendo estes (*10 FEMININOS* e *10 MASCULINOS*) e classificados em ordem alfabética pelo nome.

---

A estrutura da tabela ***`tbLista`*** é bem simples...

```
    ID - Long (500 registros)
    NOME - Texto
    SEXO - Texto (FEMININO/MASCULINO)
```

---

Este código é  que eu tenho, mas retorna somente os registros de forma aleatória...

```
SELECT TOP 20 tbNew.ID, tbNew.NOME, tbNew.SEXO
FROM (
    SELECT tbLista.ID, tbLista.NOME, tbLista.SEXO 
    FROM tbLista 
    ORDER BY Rnd(Len(ID))
) AS tbNew;
```

---

Agradeço a atenção de todos...

Comment: Gostaria de compartilhar o código que você já tentou fazer?

Comment: @StatelessDev - Eu já consegui executar o código SQL aleatório, mas sem êxito ao filtrar por gênero...

`SELECT TOP 20 tbNew.ID, tbNew.NOME, tbNew.SEXO
FROM (SELECT tbLista.ID, tbLista.NOME, tbLista.SEXO FROM tbLista ORDER BY Rnd(Len(ID)))  AS tbNew;`

Comment: Edita sua pergunta e acrescenta esse seu código lá. Fica mais fácil para o pessoal visualizar e te ajudar ;)

Comment: @StatelessDev - OK!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Funcionando:

```
SELECT tbNew.ID, tbNew.NOME, tbNew.SEXO
FROM tbLista tbNew
WHERE tbNew.ID IN (
    (SELECT TOP 10 tbLista.ID 
        FROM tbLista
        WHERE tbLista.SEXO = 'FEMININO'
        ORDER BY Rnd(Len(ID)))
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT TOP 10 tbLista.ID 
        FROM tbLista
        WHERE tbLista.SEXO = 'MASCULINO'
        ORDER BY Rnd(Len(ID)))
)
ORDER BY tbNew.SEXO, tbNew.NOME
```

---

#### Explicando:

Como você quer apenas **10 FEM e 10 MASC**, fiz **2 subqueries** sorteando-os e limitando-os individualmente e depois os uni com o `UNION ALL`.

No select externo, usei a mesma tabela para buscar os resultados de `IDs` das subqueries, e ordená-los com o `ORDER BY` no final, primeiro por `sexo`, depois por `nome`.

---

#### Auxiliares:

[Qual é a diferença entre UNION e UNION ALL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153496/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-union-e-union-all)

---

---

#### *Resposta antiga:*

*(não funcionou)*

Provavelmente, o **Access** não aceita alias para tabela, então não funcionou da dessa primeira forma que passei:

```
SELECT tbNew.ID, tbNew.NOME, tbNew.SEXO
FROM (
    (SELECT TOP 10 tbLista.ID, tbLista.NOME, tbLista.SEXO 
        FROM tbLista
        WHERE tbLista.SEXO = 'FEMININO'
        ORDER BY Rnd(Len(ID)))
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT TOP 10 tbLista.ID, tbLista.NOME, tbLista.SEXO 
        FROM tbLista
        WHERE tbLista.SEXO = 'MASCULINO'
        ORDER BY Rnd(Len(ID)))
) AS tbNew
ORDER BY tbNew.SEXO, tbNew.NOME
```

Comment: Não funcionou... "_Erro de sintaxe na operação JOIN_"

Comment: Consegui desta forma
`(SELECT TOP 10 tbLista.ID, tbLista.NOME, tbLista.SEXO FROM tbLista WHERE tbLista.SEXO = 'FEMININO' ORDER BY Rnd(Len(ID)))
UNION  ALL
(SELECT TOP 10 tbLista.ID, tbLista.NOME, tbLista.SEXO FROM tbLista WHERE tbLista.SEXO = 'MASCULINO' ORDER BY Rnd(Len(ID)))
`
Mas deste jeito não consigo ordenar por nome...

Comment: O que irá ordenar é o select externo, com alias. Tente `SELECT ID, NOME, SEXO` e `ORDER BY SEXO, NOME`, tirando o `tbNew` de todos

Comment: Cara, fiz testes aqui, está certinho. Você está executando algo junto sem querer, ou sei lá.

Comment: O erro persiste... "_`Erro de sintaxe na operação JOIN`_"
A palavra _UNION_ fica selecionada...
Até criei um novo db para executar mas, ainda não funcionou...
De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Maux Pode ser que o Access não aceite subquery da forma que fiz. Editei e fiz de outra forma. Veja se funciona.

Comment: **Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou!**