# Como fazer consulta MYSQL em 2 colunas e ordenar 1º resultados da coluna titulo e depois coluna descricao

Tags: mysql, select, order-by

Estou montando um site de agencia de emprego e tenho uma busca que procura no campo titulo e descrição, o que a pessoa procurou, conforme a consulta abaixo:

```
SELECT *
FROM vagas
WHERE (titulo LIKE '%termo_de_busca%' OR observacoes LIKE '%termo_de_busca%')
```

A consulta funciona certinho e busca nas 2 colunas, mas eu queria que ao trazer, primeiro trouxesse os resultados que tem o "termo_de_busca" na coluna titulo e depois na coluna descricao.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você terá que fazer por `subquery`:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  (SELECT * FROM vagas
  WHERE titulo LIKE '%termo_de_busca%')

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT * FROM vagas
  WHERE observacoes LIKE '%termo_de_busca%')
) as apelido
```

---

#### Explicando

Você simplesmente está fazendo 2 `selects`, unindo-os, e fazendo um `select` neles mesmo. Por fim, apelidando esse `select` de `apelido`.

**Importante**: Sempre que fizer uma *união* ( `UNION`) as 2 tabelas devem ter os mesmos campos.

---

#### edit

> Como dito pelo @RicardoPontual nos comentários, pode haver falha na
>   ordenação do `UNION`.

Caso não estiver ordenando corretamente, ou quiser ter certeza que será, crie um campo `tipo` com o valor referente:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  (SELECT *, 1 as tipo FROM vagas
  WHERE titulo LIKE '%termo_de_busca%')

  UNION ALL

  (SELECT *, 2 as tipo FROM vagas
  WHERE observacoes LIKE '%termo_de_busca%')
) as apelido
ORDER BY tipo
```

Os resultados do select pelo `titulo` o valor de `tipo` será `1` e de `observacoes` será `2`, e assim poderá ordená-los.

---

#### Links úteis

[Qual é a diferença entre UNION e UNION ALL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258431/92908)

Comment: não estaria faltando um `order by` para **garantir** que a query traga na ordem que deseja?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Postei uma resposta nova. Mas você me gerou uma dúvida: quando faço o `UNION`, ele não trará os resultados na sequencia da união?

Comment: Pois é, eu pensava assim também, assim como se fizer um select com uma coluna com *identity*, *sequence*, *auto_incremet* ou qualquer campo de chave com numeração automática, que o resultado sempre viria ordenado, mas "não há garantia" disso. Até discuti isso numa pergunta do SO e depois de pesquisar, realmente confirmamos que o banco **não garante** uma ordem, a não ser a que estiver explícita no `order by`, embora fiz vários teste com `sql server` e `mysql` e funciona esse exemplo que você colocou (union), como um campo de numeração automática (ordena por ele)

Comment: apenas comentei porque pode ocorrer algum caso que o banco retorne em outra ordem, e como não explícito o `order by`, não dá pra culpar o banco :)

Comment: Ahhh não Professor, eu prefiro que comente sempre! Assim eu aprendo mais! Depois se tiver aí, me passa o link dessa pergunta que fez que eu gostaria de ver! E obrigado pelo ensinamento! ✌️

Comment: vou testar e já posto o resultado, valeu!

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo A resposta resolveu seu problema? Caso não, corrigimos o que for necessário.

Comment: resolveu sim, obrigado, aceitei la a reposta