# Como unir resultados das consultas sem misturá-los?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Como posso unir 2 resultados de consultas sem que misture-os?

Por exemplo: A primeira consulta resulta em nomes que começam com **Vitor**, já a segunda resulta em nomes que contenham **Vitor**.

Resultado da primeira consulta:

```
Vitor A...
Vitor B...
Vitor C...
Vitor D...
```

Resultado da segunda consulta:

```
Antonio Vitor...
João Vitor...
Matheus Costa Vitor
Vitor A...
Vitor B...
Vitor C...
Vitor D...
William Vitor
```

Ao uní-los resulta em:

```
Antonio Vitor...
João Vitor...
Matheus Costa Vitor
Vitor A...
Vitor B...
Vitor C...
Vitor D...
William Vitor
```

Meu objetivo é resultar em:

```
Vitor A...
Vitor B...
Vitor C...
Vitor D...
Antonio Vitor...
João Vitor...
Matheus Costa Vitor
William Vitor
```

Estou utilizando a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT Nome
FROM Pessoa
WHERE Nome LIKE 'Vitor%'

UNION  

SELECT Nome
FROM Pessoa
WHERE Nome LIKE '%Vitor%'
```

Comment: pode inserir numa tabela temporária/em memória para retornar na mesma ordem que foram inseridos

Comment: Sim, se não torná-la muito lenta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira coisa que eu faria era garantir que o conjunto não tivesse sobreposição, assim poderíamos trabalhar com `UNION ALL`.

Como fazer isso? Simples: na segunda seleção, adicionar o filtro de que não pode começar com `Vitor`:

```
SELECT nome
FROM pessoa
WHERE nome like '%Vitor%' and nome not like 'Vitor%'
```

Unindo tudo com `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT nome
FROM pessoa
WHERE nome like 'Vitor%'
UNION ALL
SELECT nome
FROM pessoa
WHERE nome like '%Vitor%' and nome not like 'Vitor%'
```

Ok, agora precisamos conservar a ordem relativa dos elementos projetados. Dentre outras alternativas, eu gosto de colocar um classificador por cada consulta e ordenar por esse classificador:

```
SELECT nome, 1 as classificador
FROM pessoa
WHERE nome like 'Vitor%'
UNION ALL
SELECT nome, 2 as classificador
FROM pessoa
WHERE nome like '%Vitor%' and nome not like 'Vitor%'
ORDER BY classificador
```

Se precisar garantir, dentre de cada coleção de elementos, a ordem alfabética, basta colocar outras condições de ordenação **após** o classificador que eu criei:

```
SELECT nome, 1 as classificador
FROM pessoa
WHERE nome like 'Vitor%'
UNION ALL
SELECT nome, 2 as classificador
FROM pessoa
WHERE nome like '%Vitor%' and nome not like 'Vitor%'
ORDER BY classificador, nome
```

---

> Mas a minha projeção só pode conter `nome`, como faz?

Você pode por em uma subconsulta aquilo que escrevi ou numa CTE (que é uma subconsulta mais elegante). Exemplo com CTE:

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT nome, 1 as classificador
  FROM pessoa
  WHERE nome like 'Vitor%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT nome, 2 as classificador
  FROM pessoa
  WHERE nome like '%Vitor%' and nome not like 'Vitor%'
  ORDER BY classificador, nome
)
SELECT nome FROM q
```

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado, funcionou. Segundo, há diferença entre `UNION` e `UNION ALL` nesse caso? Testei ambos e retornaram os mesmos resultados.

Comment: Outra pergunta, entre o `and` e `not like 'Vitor%'` não teria que colocar `nome`, assim ficando `and nome not like 'Vitor%'`?

Comment: @Focos mais mesmo de que `UNION ALL` é uma operação mais simples e trabalha menos. Como eu tenho a garantia que o resultado da operação será exatamente igual (vide o diferencial de tuplas), eu prefiro usar `UNION ALL`. Tem também uma questão algebraica, eu prefiro trabalhar com _bags_ do que com conjuntos, e `UNION` é operação de conjunto. Respondi um pouco disso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258431/64969

Comment: @Focos sobre esse segundo comentário: erro de digitação, obrigado por perceber

Comment: @Focos deve ter um jeito mais otimizado de por esse `nome LIKE '%vitor%' AND nome NOT LIKE 'vitor%`, mas não sou um grande conhecedor de outros metacaracteres do `LIKE`